# Purim Torah policy - Allowed, but regulated

Tags: support, faq, policy, purim-torah-policy

We pride ourselves on generating and maintaining clear, high-quality, serious [questions and answers about Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Once a year, though, for a couple of weeks, we also go in for something a little ... different.

## Purim Torah Q&A

[Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah), silly parodies of real Torah discussion, is a way to loosen up during the [Purim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim) season, and look at Torah concepts from a new and creative vantage point:

[image: A man's image distorted in a fun house mirror]
<sup>"[Henry & The Funhouse Mirror](https://www.flickr.com/photos/biblicone/3002713749)," by [mob mob](https://www.flickr.com/photos/biblicone/), used [with permission](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.0/)</sup>

We want to have this fun<sup>1</sup> without compromising our carefully-cultivated regular Q&A, so there are some rules:

### When

Post Purim Torah questions between [Rosh Chodesh Adar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Chodesh) [Bet, if [there is one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Hebrew_calendar)] and a day or two after Purim, *only*<sup>2</sup>.

- **5784/2024:** Nightfall on **March 9** until nightfall on **March 26**.

Please don't edit or otherwise bump old Purim Torah posts except during this period.

### What

It's gotta be distinctly **"Purim"** (not serious), distinctly **Torah**, and distinctly **Q&A**. Purim Torah questions that don't have all three of these qualities may be closed.<sup>3</sup>

So, post sincere-*looking* **questions** (you know, the kind that invite **answers**) that:

- **misinterpret** a real **Torah** concept or Jewish text

or

- apply a distinctly **Torah** style (e.g. Talmudic analysis) to an **irrelevant** topic

Post **answers** in the same spirit<sup>4</sup> as their questions, so no completely serious answers to Purim Torah questions, and no silly answers to serious (non-Purim-Torah) questions.

Please try to put as much attention into [question quality](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), [answer quality](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), and above all, [Being Nice!](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), as you would for regular Mi Yodeya content.

### And (Don't skip!)

We don't want to confuse anyone, so please mark your Purim Torah questions in these **three** ways:

- Apply the tag [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) *and no other tag*.<sup>5</sup>
- Begin [your](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4508/759) title with `PTIJ:`
- Include the following disclaimer text at the bottom:

  `---`

  `# This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/). #`

---

### Moderation Stuff

- Close<sup>6</sup> Purim Torah questions that aren't **"Purim"**, **Torah**, and **questions**.
- At the end of Purim Torah season, delete all Purim Torah questions that were closed as not "**"Purim"**, **Torah**, and **questions**."
- At the end of the Purim Torah season, close all open Purim Torah questions as "Off-Topic" with the close comment:

> **Purim Torah** questions are on-topic only once a year, and will be closed after Purim. For details, see: [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated)

- Remember to close open PTIJ questions on meta, too.
- If you want an old Purim Torah question re-opened during this year's season, ask the moderators.

---

<sup>1. For what it's worth, [Joel Spolsky](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/503/joel-spolsky) endorsed this policy [Stack Exchange Podcast #32](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/se-podcast-32-jarrod-dixon-and-josh-heyer/) (~33:50 - 36:40) and again on [#55](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/podcast-55-dont-call-it-a-comeback/) (~44:00 - 47:30).</sup>
<sup>2. Of course, serious questions are also allowed and encouraged during this period!</sup>
<sup>3. On [Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-purim-torah-in-jest), Purim Torah has to be *about Mi Yodeya*, not necessarily about Judaism itself.</sup>
<sup>4. No pun intended.</sup>
<sup>5. On Meta, apply the tags [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [meta-purim-torah-in-jest](/questions/tagged/meta-purim-torah-in-jest).</sup>
<sup>6. Use "Off-topic/Other" as the reason.</sup>

Comment: Rosh Chodesh Adar (I and II) is always a two day rosh chodesh. Is 30 Shevat / 30 Adar I included or excluded from play?

Comment: @DoubleAA, depends when _sanhedrin_ announces the new month. Stay tuned.

Comment: @DoubleAA, They started in with the "Shoshanat Ya'akov" tune in my shul already this past Shabbat, at Birkat Hachodesh. I think the first day of Rosh Chodesh is fine. Note that in the post, I specified tonight at sundown as the start point for this year. Note also that as I said above, I think that we don't need to enforce the time limits with very close precision. We just want to keep this feature reasonably in check.

Comment: @IsaacMoses My minhag is to begin "Shoshanas Yaakov" Motzoei Shabbes Mevorchin Adar Rishon. May I post Purim Torah in Adar I too?

Comment: @NBZ In accordance with a famous [ruling](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1755/2) of R' Moshe Feinstein, you may follow your differing minhag around here, but only silently. So, you may post your Purim Torah in Adar I and delete it before anyone else reads it, then undelete in Adar II.

Comment: Let's encourage good intelligent and funny Purim Torah. However, I am disappointed at the quality of some of the posts. It may be Purim, but the Torah still requires refined, respectful behavior. I think the posts should be monitored for questions that don't meet the ethical and quality standards we expect from Mi Yodeya.

Comment: How is "sundown" and "the evening hours" marking the start and end of this period calculated when the site is on UTC?

Comment: @Thunderforge not calculated, observed, [imprecisely but strictly](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated#comment1811_797), by people.

Comment: Can we post purim torah on Purim Katan?

Comment: @SamuelManuel [Nope.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3839/mei-eimatai-kotvin-et-hapurim-torah)

Comment: I wasn't sure how best to include that you shouldn't edit old posts to apply PTIJ to the title, so i included a link. if oyu have a better way please edit

Comment: I'm assuming yom kippur is not considered purim for this.  Right?

Comment: @Shababnik No need to assume. The dates are specified in this post.

Comment: We may need to include something about ChatGPT generated content