# Should we change the flag system?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

Currently the site uses 'flags' to mark a comment as unconstructive (a word not recognized by the Merriam-Webster dictionary or our site's spell check by the way), offensive, or spam. However in Yiddishkeit a flag is generally seen as a positive thing. In fact the word used for a flag is 'Nes' which also means a miraculous intervention by God.

This may confuse users who will believe that 'flagging' a comment is an indication that it is somehow miraculous. As such, perhaps we should change the system.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Also, note, all questions tagged with 'bugs' should be properly checked

Comment: *All* questions should be checked for bugs, whether they're immediately apparent or not. Perhaps we could use something like [this](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) to aid in the checking.

Comment: is it flagging or flogging?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yoma 68b tells us that they used to wave flags as a signal that the scapegoat (of Yom Kippur) had reached the desert and was on its way to its death, carrying all of the sins of the Jewish people on it.

Here, too, then, the flags signify a post that has transgressed the rules and must be terminated with extreme prejudice (though maybe not to the extent of throwing it off a cliff).

Comment: I disagree. ......... We should _definitely_ throw 'em off a cliff.