# How do we treat questions that are Asur to ask?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

Some questions, [like this one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26391/5), are anticipated by [Halachic decisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posek) and [are expressly prohibited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26391/hefsek-between-hagafen-and-drinking-during-havdallah#comment59860_26391). How should we treat them on Mi Yodeya? Should we delete them? Should we close them but keep them visible to future visitors so they know they ought not to be asked? Dare we answer them and risk encouraging more such questions?

---

<sup>The question refers to the break between the blessing on the wine at Havdallah, and actually drinking the wine, during which time other blessings and the remainder of Havdallah are recited. The Hebrew comment on that question was a quote from the ערוך השולחן, which states:</sup>

> <sup>ואין לשאול: "למה בקידוש והבדלה ברכת 'בורא פרי הגפן' קודמת לשארי ברכות?"‏</sup>

<sup>or in English:</sup>

> <sup>And do not ask: "Why at Kiddush and Havdallah does the blessing '[He Who] createth the fruit of the vine' precede the remaining blessings?"</sup>

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I was about to challenge your assumption until I saw the tag. Nicely done. :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Psalm 6 describes the woes of the Mi Yodeya moderator. It tells what happens when inappropriate questions are asked:

> בשאול מי יודע לך יגעתי באנחתי אשחה בכל לילה מטתי בדמעתי ערשי אמסה ... סורו ממני כל פעלי און כי שמע יהוה קול בכיי ... יבשו ויבהלו מאד כל איבי ישבו יבשו רגע
>
> *When you ask for yourself on Mi Yodeya, I am weary with my groaning; every night I make my bed to swim; I melt away my couch with my tears... Depart from me, all ye workers of iniquity; for the LORD hath heard the voice of my weeping... All mine enemies shall be ashamed and sore affrighted; they shall turn back, they shall be ashamed suddenly.*

It seems that the proper procedure is to become sad and frustrated and to cry to God for help. He will make the OPs feel shame and fright in asking such questions, and they will do so no longer.