# Is one allowed to have a Tree as a logo of Mi Yodeya?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

This is a virtual beis medrash.
A Beis Medrash is greater than a Shul.
A Shul is like the Beis Hamikdash.
One is not allowed to have a tree in the Beis Hamikdash, so kal vachomer not in a beis medrash.

You will claim that this only a *virtual* tree, so it shouldn't be a problem. I'll answer that this beis medrash is also only virtual. So our logo is now a virtual Asheira.

Good Going guys.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Leitz,, where have I seen your gravatar before?

Comment: I'm pretty sure [this](http://www.vbm-torah.org/) is a Virtual Beit Midrash.

Answer (score 0):

You will note that the tree stands at the top of the page -- at the entrance, you might say.  That's different from one that's inside the hall.

Comment: Actually the prohibition on planting a tree in the Mikdash is really on all of the Azara (courtyard, where the outer altar was) not just in the building.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the logo is an etz chaim.  An asherah looks like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aNMMI_IMG_8966.JPG) (don't look if you don't want to pollute your eyes . . .)