# Is a golem logo appropriate for this site?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

One is not allowed to think Torah thoughts in a bathroom. Here this site doubts my humanity so I see this "golem". However, while I was thinking some Torah, I saw this inappropriately dressed humanoid.

Maybe someone should put some clothes on him?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I am very confused by this... What does this mean?

Comment: @Daniel Is this site a Beis Hakissei?