# Should we flag outside of Israel?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

[The *Bavli*, *M'gila* 14](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=1439) says:

> שאין אומרים הלל על נס שבחוצה לארץ
> We do not praise a flag that is outside of Israel.

Should we non-Israelis [flag](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) posts on Mi Yodeya?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They may flag, but in order not to praise it the mods will never mark such a flag as helpful.

Comment: *That's* why mods have access to users' location information! Now it all makes sense. +1.

Comment: And for this reason, plus *lifnei iver*, users should not tell us from where they flag so that we do not have to decline those flags.

Comment: I forgot it was Purim Torah and nearly dug a hole _to_ Israel after seeing the meta front page.

Comment: @TimPost, in case you're wondering, a more usual translation of the Hebrew in the question is "we do not say the _halel_ (praise) prayer for a miracle [that took place] outside of Israel". The same word in Hebrew can mean "miracle" and "flag".