# Incorrect assingment of reputation points?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

The current system for awarding reputation points is 5 points for a vote on a question, and 10 points for a vote on an answer.

However, the מאמר הכחם says - שאלת חכם חצי תשובה, a wise question is half of the answer.  It would seem that the correct way to allot points would be that each time an answer is upvoted, the questioner should get half the points, as well as half the points when an answer is accepted.

Perhaps we have misunderstood this to mean that a wise question is worth half as much as an answer?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/799

Comment: @msh210 That was kind of my אין לומר pshat.  Or perhaps ברוך שכוונתי

Comment: I didn't know you could ask a purim torah question in meta? How about giving people reputation for meta activity?

Comment: @ClintEastwood If we turned on rep on a child meta, even for a while, we'd also open up the possibility for negative rep - something we probably don't want. It's just a little fun.