# Should we stop using the ashera tree as our logo?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

Not sure how this got past the mods, but I think it would be appropriate if we changed our logo and stopped using the image of an Ashera tree to represent this site.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).