# Requesting Purim Torah answers to serious-looking questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, policy, purim-torah-policy

The *[Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/797/70)* addresses question that are, themselves, in the Purim spirit. But there is also Purim Torah which takes for its starting point a “real” question; only the answer is ridiculous.

For a concrete example, take this pseudo-analysis of a serious topic:
*[Women and Tefillin: a Response to Everyone](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9p_0xPmPsBaZ1Baa0Q1Nl9iUmVuOTNDX1M0QVhGbzExOTdV)*.
Can something like this be posted to Mi Yodeya? I see two possibilities:

1. The rules do not change; find a way to make the question silly on its own. For the example, the question would be something like, “May women wear *tefillin* just as Queen Esther did?”.
2. The question can be asked “straight” (“May women wear *tefillin*?”), but tagged [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest), and with a variant of the usual disclaimer specifically asking **only** for Purim Torah-type answers.

The first is the obvious answer, but has a drawback: I may need to have a particular answer in mind, and the wording of the question may only allow for joke answers along that one narrow path.

Comment: That article is hilarious.

Comment: @DoubleAA, whatever the decision on my question, someone’s going to have to ask her for permission. Here’s the [original post](https://www.facebook.com/channa.bob/posts/10202225840260844), BTW.