# PTIJ: How do I sign up with the Department of Mi Yodeya Security or other Mi Yodeya organizations?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

[Apparently](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4720/are-questions-of-the-form-rabbi-so-and-so-wrote-a-sefer-on-x-jewish-topic-but/4721#comment14714_4721), Mi Yodeya has a special Department of Security. Where can I sign up?

I see we also have a [Brotherhood of Hebrew HNQ Monitors](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49463681#49463681), which [apparently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49463714#49463714) is lacking members at the moment. Where do I sign up there?

Any other organizations I should know about?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

There's also the [International Brotherhood of Lightbulb-Changers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89791/1569), which is of course part of Mi Yodeya (when I asked them who they're affiliated with, they shrugged and said, "Who knows?").

They are said to have a very difficult entrance exam. I approve of their high standards: I, for one, wouldn't let anyone change my lightbulb who doesn't speak 70 languages and know 150 ways to purify a *sherets*.

Comment: by the way, the gra has a super cute vort on 150 ways to be metaher es hasheretz. Are you familiar with it?

Comment: @רבותמחשבות No, what is it?

Comment: see the first vort here: http://daf-yomi.com/forums/message.aspx?Id=17410