# Favorite close reason

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

My favorite close reason is Primarily Opinion Based.

What's yours?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: *laugh*  That was fast!

Comment: any good questions generate some degree of oPinion based on expert experience, bUt answeRs to thIs question will tend to be alMost enTirely based On opinions, RAtHer than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55155/759

Answer (score 11):

Sometimes I will use audible close reasons that do not post correctly to the web site.  You have to be standing within a few feet of me to pick them up.

Examples:

- What?
- Are you nuts?
- Does your mind *actually* work that way?
- Oh *this* guy again!

Answer (score 5):

My favorite flag on answers is "it is not an answer."

Comment: You bozo! Learn to read! The question was about *comment* flag reasons. Also, your answer should start with "my favorite." Speaking of which, let's have a comment thread about other favorite things.

Comment: Are you too dense to realize that the best comments are the sarcastic belligerent ones with lots of punctuation marks?????

Comment: (15 characters)

Answer (score 3):

My favorite close reason for Purim is *too broad*, because some people are going to be *too broad* after eating all that Purim junk!

Answer (score 3):

http://amerock.com/functional/hinge-self-closing.html

[http://www.amazon.com/Amerock-TEN3428G10-Decorative-Self-Closing-10-Pack/dp/B003FMVJN2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003FMVJN2)

AMEROCK MAKES THE BEST SELF-CLOSING HINGES!!!!!!!

Comment: (Someone just actually flagged this as spam...)

Comment: @DoubleAA (Don't delete me, bro!)

Answer (score 0):

My fave is "off topic because of other...". I can write whatever I want, there. Then, the O.P. can't even debate my reason if the question is closed. I win, again, HAHAHAHA :-)