# Is closing a M.Y. question because it is "primarily opinion-based" a matter of opinion?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

Many M.Y. questions are closed for the "opinion-based" reason. To me, that seems like a matter of 4 people's opinions, or just the moderator's opinion.

That's my opinion on this policy. What's yours?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: @IsaacMoses - LOL! I think you're right, but, that's your opinion, for now...

Answer (score 7):

No. You're wrong.

Comment: You're right too!

Comment: @HodofHod http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/858/759

Comment: @DoubleAA I was _wondering_ if anyone would remember that. Hats off to you, my friend.

Answer (score 6):

You're absolutely right!

Comment: This answer doesn't provide sources or an argument and I recommend deletion.

Comment: I agree!  ​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @HodofHod - You can downvote it, too. But then, you have to voice your opinion about why.