# What if your Orthodox rabbi tells you to ask your question on Mi Yodeya?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

I can't tell you how often this has happened...

I ask my Ortodox rabbi a question. He doesn't know the answer, and suggests that I ask it on Mi Yodeya. (He knows about this site and sometimes uses it.)

So, I ask the question, I don't have it closed, but the only one or two answers I get say, "ask my rabbi".

This is very frustrating. What am I supposed to do? Find a different rabbi who will tell me the same thing?

I'm quite sure that I'm not the only one who has this situation.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: __Phew!__ At least _one_ of our users is an Orthodox Rabbi!

Comment: @DoubleAA - You mean, it's not you?

Comment: @DanF doubleAA might be a woman rabbi, so not orthodox

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Wow, what a great question.  You should consult your local orthodox rabbi about it.

Comment: Arrrgggghhhh!!!

Answer (score 23):

You follow his instructions: you ask on Mi Yodeya and report the results to him.  Mi Yodeya says to ask your rabbi, so you're back to him.  If he doesn't know then he can ask Mi Yodeya -- where his question will be closed as a duplicate of yours, but along the way he'll get the advice to "ask your rabbi".

Surely your rabbi has a rabbi?  So if he doesn't know, he needs to ask his rabbi for guidance.

Somehow I think this isn't the first case of that being the answer.

Comment: Monica - Y'know? There must be a reason why you were made a moderator. As confusing as this answer is, it makes sense, even though I don't quite like it :-) BTW - is the avatar a pic of you?

Comment: @DanF the gravatar is a representation of me that is loosely tied to reality.  Were it an actual picture, that mug might be a can or bottle of Diet {Coke, Pepsi}. :-)

Comment: Too much aspartame in your life, huh? Or is Pittsburgh getting to you, finally?

Comment: Prefer sucralose, but aspartame if necessary.  (So, Pepsi One or Coke Zero if available, but often they're not.)  It's really about caffeine without sugar.