# Stack Overflow Inc., sinat chinam, and the goat for Azazel

Tags: discussion, moderators

On Friday, half an hour before [Shabbat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbat) and two days before [Rosh Hashana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosh_Hashanah), Stack Overflow Inc. suddenly revoked my moderator status on all sites where I had it.  I found this out while handling flags, when I suddenly got notifications for Marshal and Deputy badges (which moderators are ineligible to earn).  They did this not because I've done anything to violate SE policies (*which I have not done*), but because they *think* I will in the *future* violate a thoughtcrime-style provision of a Code of Conduct change that hasn't been made yet.

Rather than just asking you to take my word for everything, let me quote something that [another moderator who has no particular ties to me wrote](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1650):

> Social life means being confronted to different points of view. This is especially true on in an international setting such as Stack Exchange where you get to encounter people from different cultures. When interacting with others, you need to draw lines — for example, racism is not acceptable, full stop — and within those bounds, you need to open up to diversity. Sometimes that means listening to multiple points of view, and sometimes agree to disagree, and sometimes compromise.
>
> I have witnessed a disagreement between moderators where both sides made some good points. Both sides deserved and requested respect. One side was aware that their behavior could hurt even though no malice was intended and tried to get out of their way not to be hurtful. The other side demanded to have things their way, and did not care who they were hurting on the process. In this particular dispute, there was clearly a victim and aggressors.
>
> Stack Exchange intervened, did not try to calm spirits, came firmly on the uncompromising side, and fired the victim in a very hurtful manner.

The behavior that Gilles describes happened in the Teachers' Lounge, a private chat room for moderators.  I was the victim.  Someone with a "director" job title had dropped into the room to announce an upcoming change to the Code of Conduct; unlike the rest of the CoC, this rule mandates specific, positive actions.<sup>1</sup>  I raised some issues with the formation of the policy and asked some questions, the vast majority of which were never answered.  I was polite and was trying to work with others to solve a problem I have with the change as presented.

After a couple hours, the director responded, chastising me for raising issues and saying my values were out of alignment.  I said I would leave the room to avoid causing problems, and did so.  The Teachers' Lounge is a *resource* for moderators, but there is no requirement to participate there and many moderators do not.  This appeared to be a TL-centric issue.

Two days later (Friday September 20), after a lot more discussion, a community manager instructed people to send email if they have concerns.  I did so in the minutes before Shabbat.

On Monday I received email from a different CM explaining why they were making the change and mis-stating some issues I had raised.  Concerned that I had not made myself clear in my haste to respond quickly on Friday, I replied with some questions.  This was an amicable exchange; I thought we were having a productive conversation.  I was promised a reply by this past Friday.

Instead, I saw my diamond disappear before my eyes and briefly saw an announcement from a CM in TL that contained false allegations against me. When I tried to respond I was booted from the room.  Around this time I received email firing me.  This email did not cite anything I have done wrong; this was a pre-emptive move that runs counter to how SE tells moderators to treat users when considering suspensions.  (Moderators suspend in response to behavior, not speculatively.)

In TL and now in answers here and elsewhere, Stack Exchange employees made vague statements implying that I oppose inclusion and respectful behavior, which is false and adds insult on top of the injury already done.  I suspect a profound misunderstanding is at the root of their behavior, but all of my attempts to resolve it have gone unanswered.  It feels to me like the company prefers a scapegoat to a resolution.

If I had *done* anything to violate the Code of Conduct, I would apologize and try to make it right or bow out.  I didn't violate this important code (and especially not the code currently in force!), and I find it especially offensive that I am being accused of behavior that is not welcoming, inclusive, and sensitive when these are things I strive for in all of my interactions on the network (and elsewhere).

Last November, in the wake of a different controversy around SE employees maligning moderators in public, Tim Post made a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) promising moderators five things: trust, support, agency, accountability, and autonomy.  The actions that Stack Overflow took in the last week and a half violate all five of those.

It has been an honor to serve this community.

---

<sup>1</sup> Now that this has been [made public elsewhere](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6718/4145), I feel safe in saying more.  The policy is an update to the Code of Conduct that requires us to use people's preferred pronouns (when known).  What was posted in the TL wasn't polished language; I assume they're working on that.  I **completely agree** that it is rude to call people what they don't want to be called; knowingly misgendering someone is not ok.  But the policy was about positive, not negative, use of pronouns.  I pointed out that as a professional writer I, by training, write in a gender-neutral way specifically to *avoid* gender landmines, and sought clarification that this would continue to be ok.  To my surprise, other moderators in the room said that *not using (third-person singular) pronouns at all* is misgendering.  The employee never clarified, and this is one of the questions I asked in email.  In my email I said clearly that I'm on board with "use preferred pronouns *when using pronouns*", but from the fact that they fired me without warning (or answering the question), I conclude that that's not the policy.  I haven't seen an actual policy, though I am being accused of violating it.

---

Related blog posts:

- [Stack Overflow Inc. has sunk to new lows](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/02/stack-overflow-purge.html) (2019-10-02)
- [Stack Overflow Inc.: what we say vs. what we do](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/03/stack-overflow-ignores-its-own-rules.html) (2019-10-03)
- [Stack Overflow Inc. fiasco: timeline](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/05/stack-overflow-fiasco-timeline.html) (2019-10-05)
- (Not a blog post): [David Fullerton, CTO, made a partial apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/334551/162102), not for what they did but how they did some of it, and promised me direct contact.  You can track that contact in [my answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334646/162102); see also the next blog post.  (His post was 2019-10-06; unsatisfactory email was sent 2019-10-08.)
- [Stack Overflow Inc.: radio silence continues](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/13/stack-overflow-silence.html) (2019-10-13)
- [Stack Overflow Inc.: more delays](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/15/stack-overflow-delays.html) (2019-10-15)
- [Stack Overflow Inc.: flawed policies posted](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/22/stack-overflow-new-process-flaws.html) (contains links to removal and reinstatement policies and my response) (2019-10-22)
- [Stack Overflow is doing me ongoing harm; it's time to fix it!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/162102) (Meta.SE), cross-posted on my [blog](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2019/10/23/stack-overflow-stop-the-damage.html) (2019-10-23)
- [GoFundMe page for legal costs](https://www.gofundme.com/f/stop-stack-overflow-from-defaming-its-users) (2019-10-28), closed 2019-12-23
- [Podcast interview](https://cellio.dreamwidth.org/2067495.html) (2019-11-01)

I still **have not been shown** what specifically I am supposed to have done wrong, though I am told that a community manager told other moderators I have been.  Sara's privacy-violating defamatory accusations **continue to cause me ongoing harm**, which is actually the larger problem.

Comment: I would welcome a similar post on meta.stackexchange.com so we can express support there as well

Comment: Thanks @mbloch; I'll consider that tomorrow.  I didn't get much sleep last night nor rest today, so I'm going to (try to) sleep on that.  (I'm likely to attract the same kinds of personal attacks there that I received in TL, so have to decide if it's worth it.)

Comment: If you wouldn't mind sharing a copy of the email you received, as well as what you best remember of the false allegations made against you, that would be very nice.

Comment: By director do you mean CM?

Comment: Aside a few mods leaving recently for various reasons, several moderators have left across the network because of this (in protest). SE is going to feel this one

Comment: I could tell you were on your way out. Truth to power doesn't sit well with SE

Comment: [This has been referenced on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333965/332043)

Comment: Of all the people for this to possibly happen to, you are the absolute last person who I’d suspect of abusing mod privileges. You’ve been nothing but helpful and kind in your interactions on SE; while I mostly stick to MY, I’ve seen you in action on other sites also, particularly Worldbuilding, and see the same pattern there. I can’t believe this would happen, and know that you have our full support.

Comment: Hey, Monica. I haven't been around on Stack Exchange much in the past few months. But from what I remember about your interactions in the TL, you were always civil and courteous even while raising objections to the norm or during the so-called arguments. You were certainly one of the ideal moderators on the network. It's extremely unfortunate that this incident happened. Nevertheless, good luck with all your future endeavors. Stay well!

Comment: In the political language, "diversity" means "conformity" - and siding with the aggressor instead of the victim, this is kind of behavior, which one can often find among narcissistic psychopaths. Their words simply do not match their actions. Don't try to understand them (for your own sanity), because there is nothing to understand - ze rak meshuggah.

Comment: I made a new account here just to write this - I'm appalled by this action and the lack of response forthcoming. As far as I'm concerned, this is nigh on unforgivable.

Comment: Wow, that's.... I don't know what to say. Please know that you are by far the best person I have met that could be a moderator on any of the sites I have visited throughout my time here on the StackExchange network. StackExchange has done a lot of bad things in the past that I didn't like, but this...? This is on a whole different level...

Comment: "...my values were out of alignment..." Often enough it looks like StackExchange's values are out of alignment lately. Anyway, thanks Monica for your great work. It is always a nice experience reading your thoughtful contributions.

Comment: I didn't know you before [gilles posted on FL](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/q/752/358), and from all the comments one can tell you are a great person.  I just joined to let you know how infuriating I find SE behaviour.

Comment: Monica is the role model moderator - the exemplary moderator all other moderators should look up to. Can someone clear up this gross communication failure?

Comment: Friday has never been a good day to "ship", set new things in motion, sacking, or other drastic measures. If memory is a problem, write it down (a good idea in any case), consider it over several nights of sleep, and then do it early in the week. -

Comment: cont': Process, like [Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29), may interfere, though. This is the second time within two months something like this happens for Stack Exchange on a Friday.

Comment: I'm shocked - I've always seen you as an excellent, even-handed moderator. I don't know the full context, but this seems egregiously unfair.

Comment: I've always had positive interactions with you. I have a very hard time believing that there was any kind of misconduct (intentional or otherwise), and vague insinuations from SE [won't change that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389906/im-resigning-as-a-moderator-from-all-stack-exchange-sites-effective-today#comment730817_389908).

Comment: Like @Magisch, I'm making a new account here just to write how upset I am about this and to express how positive an impact on SE I've always seen you have.

Comment: I too just joined to upvote this and to say that I have always though of you as one of the best moderators. I wish you the best at whatever you choose to do next

Comment: Good luck, whatever happens. I've always seen you as one of the core SE users; apparently they think you're a disposable tool.

Comment: Monica, are we losing you on Writing.SE too?

Comment: So sorry to read about this, Monica.  Stack Exchange was a much better place with you than without.

Comment: Is there any way we could get a more concrete account of what happened?  I mean, I usually have a good opinion of both StackExchange's employees and the moderation staff, including @MonicaCellio, such that it's unexpected to see issues like this.  Given this unexpected development, it'd be good to have a concrete assessment of the situation to better make sense of it.  (It'd probably be easier to make assumptions if I thought one side of this was malicious, but since that's not the case, it's a bit more complicated.)

Comment: @April et al, yeah, they stripped Monica of her diamonds on every site she was a moderator for.  I may not remember the full list but it does include: Mi Yodeya, Writing, Worldbuilding, and Meta.

Comment: @Cyn You forgot [Beer, Wine & Spirits](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/84639) and [The Workplace](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6314/63243)

Comment: I'd like to know more about the statements which the company claims justified this response. I don't see it mentioned in this post, and depending on what they were, reactions could be very different.

Comment: @Cyn, Dang, it looks like I maybe got my wish, that BOTH candidates in Writing.SE could have gotten elected.

Comment: What happened to your answer - the one where you provided extra details? Did you yourself remove it?

Comment: The moderators of Writing.SE have put out a statement.  https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2228/se-has-removed-a-moderator

Comment: [Not my platform!](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1744774/gerold-broser?tab=profile)

Comment: For comparison, the top voted question on the main site only has +119 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12760/implications-of-samoa-skipping-a-friday

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I deleted that answer pending a more careful review of my notes, rather than writing only from memory, after learning that at least one person had thought I was talking about someone I wasn't.  I do intend to update it and undelete, but maybe not tonight.  Frankly, I'm tired and a lot of stuff piled up over the holiday.

Comment: Most often people represent their side of the story in self-supporting ways or with embellishments. To better understand what took place, I tracked through the comments in the Teacher's Lounge and found your recounting of things to be quite factual. I don't think you did anything wrong. Discussing new policies and expressing your opinion is what the chat rooms and Meta is all about. Through an open discussion, policies get clarified and improved upon where needed.In this case, it appears policies were enforced that have yet to even be announced. This seems very _wrong_ and heavy-handed to me..

Comment: @FilipMilovanović actually, I think I can cover the salient points in the question itself.  See my update (the footnote).

Comment: Thanks for the review, @dan.  I know we always start out biased toward our own perspective so I tried to be careful, but I was also writing in haste due to the circumstances.  I *try* to fairly represent events that I'm reporting; being an imperfect human I don't always get it right, but I think it's an important trait for a person, and especially a person in any position of authority or influence, to pursue.

Comment: This is not how I ever expected to earn Great Answer and Famous Question badges on meta...

Comment: @MonicaCellio We're all human beings, until they replace all the moderators with AI bots (at least you won't have to suffer that indignation).  And you seem like a fairly respectful and sensitive one to me, so it's kind of ironic that the issue of respect and _sensitivity_ is what initiated this. Have hope though, I hear a [petition](http://chng.it/WsXNZMgRfk) has been started based on the comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper?noredirect=1#comment1091837_333965).

Comment: It must be some solace to at least know how well-liked and supported you are…and you're still alive to hear all the accolades :-) Happy New Year btw (it might end up not so bad in the end).

Comment: Note for the non-Jews out there: The anti-negative (don't do the bad thing) rather than the positive (do the good thing) has Jewish roots. The most obvious example being the golden rule: "Do onto other's as you would like done to you" leads to logical issues (What if I like being hit with a stick? Should I assume you like the same? When I want dinner, should I buy enough for the entire world? What if you don't like the same food I like? etc), and therefore is given by Rav Hillel as "Do not do to others what is hateful to you." I can see gendering falling into the same logical traps.

Comment: The way I explain the problem with Golden Rule (when teaching Tech Writing, the Ethics sections) is imagine Bert & Ernie (Sesame Street) as roommates.  Bert buys ice cream for himself, assumes if Ernie wanted it, he'd buy it for himself.  Ernie views it as a community resource, eats some ice cream, and next time he goes shopping *he'll* buy ice cream.  So Bert thinks Ernie is a jerk, when Ernie was just applying a different "as you would have done unto you" to the situation.  He thinks of the kitchen as a communal space, not a grouping of individual items with distinct ownership.

Comment: Monica, I hope you see this through all the cruft, I bet your inbox is overloaded. I noticed staff didn't actually answer any of your questions or clarify anything at all in the TL discussions, did you ever get answers or clarifications about policy questions over email or another medium? And did they at any time answer your question that yes, your diamonds are in danger?

Comment: @Kevin nope.  I got one piece of email explaining why they're making this change, I replied with questions (including the one, again, about whether they mean *when using pronouns* or something more proactive), and got no further reply, though I was promised one (more than once).  Instead, four days later, they fired me.  About diamonds, they said that if I can't get on board with the new policy it would be better for me to resign now, but there was no threat and since there were questions still pending about the policy, I didn't think that signalled imminent action.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but not unexpected. For what it's worth, I support you and your points of view in the situation, and they haven't clarified or answered anything about the new terms in the TL since either.

Comment: @Monica How accurate is [this article](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2019/10/01/stack_exchange_controversy/) in summing up the situation?

Comment: @DonielF the description of the teams question is accurate (those are my words).  The moderator who linked to the post in TL was not the one who asked the question, and that moderator used the word "bigot" or "bigoted" in reference to me/my answer (that part's from memory).  Sara's claims that I violated the CoC are wrong (as already noted).  Tangentially, I also question her claim that they take the CoC seriously given things that were said to me in TL in front of employees with no action.

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm sorry to hear that you are on the receiving end of such action. My personal experience with you on Mi Yodeya has been consistently fair and even-handed. It's hard to imagine how anyone who has actually had contact with you can associate 'exclusionary' as one of your character traits. The loss to SE will ultimately be an aliyah for you, with G-d's help. May you be completely sealed for revealed good only. I didn't even know that the Moderators can/do get some kind of remuneration from SE.

Comment: @YaacovDeane moderators don't get paid, aside from the occasional t-shirt or hat back when the company did swag.  I think "fired" applies to getting rid of volunteers, too.  Sorry for any confusion.  (And thanks for what you wrote.  Seeing the outpouring of support from my community has helped make a terrible situation a little less terrible.)

Comment: I am not even of your religious beliefs, Monica and I find this whole thing so distasteful. Whatever happens, I do wish you all the best. May the G-d of Abraham, Issac and Jacob look after you!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334551/an-apology-to-our-community-and-next-steps

Comment: I am not of any religious belief, but I signed up here explicitly to express my support for you, Monica. It sounds like I do much the same as you do (use specific descriptors in place of pronouns whenever possible) and for much the same reason. I believe your concerns were valid, and I believe you were treated very poorly by the network. I hope things work out in your favor.

Comment: Just a note of a private follow up in another forum where I attend. Here linked to because I think it is (at least a bit) helpful for the personal, but also for the larger aspect of the thing.  https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/on-a-current-event-in-a-commercial-forum-widely-managed-by-volunteer-moderators/14005 . Appreciating your stand and that of the part of the community which speak out, and especially that who stand for ethical standards explicitely.

Comment: Looks like Stack Exchange is the latest addition to the list of communities that have been infiltrated and subjugated by political correctness and identity politics. Sadly, Monica is just a recent addition to the long list of people who have been victimized by this supposedly "progressive" movement. Sadly, I had a feeling something like this was going to eventually happen to SE and I was right. The same will probably happen to all of our communities eventually, and most of us will be banned or marginalized from them for not blindly following the herd

Comment: P.S. they're apparently mass-deleting answers and comments on the post announcing the new CoC change. I just checked it and it turns out that like a good half of the answers and comments people posted (most of which were very thoughtful, detailed and respectful) have been completely deleted.

Comment: a new "Affaire Dreyfuss"?

Comment: Wow.  One step closer to Minority Report. You'll triumph in the end, Monica--you deserve it.

Comment: So glad to hear that there’s potential for their reinstating you - hope all goes well and looking forward to having you back soon! Have you feeling any better over Yom Tov?

Comment: @DonielF I hope so.  I will not be surprised if the process is rigged against me, but the only way to know is to try.  I wrote a lot more on my blog (i.e. not SE's platform).  Sukkot was less bad than the yamim noraim were -- trying to get into that whole "rejoice" angle.  It's still hard, though; SE is causing ongoing hurt and it looks like that'll continue for at least a few more weeks. There is a human cost that they don't seem to care about. :-(

Comment: @MonicaCellio If that fails, is there anything preventing us from just holding moderator elections and voting you back in?

Comment: @DonielF SE might veto my candidacy; they've fordibly withdrawn candidates before.  (Speculating; I don't know more than you do on that.)  After all, the *Mi Yodeya* community didn't ask for me to be removed, either.

Comment: @MonicaCellio So much for democratically elected. Sounds more like fascist or socialist “elections” where the government got to decide who could be on the ballot. Oy.

Comment: Has anyone else observed the irony that @MonicaCellio herself posted [a question several years ago about how Stack Overflow might handle a situation like this](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1224/4143)?

Comment: For several weeks, I had been considering coming back to BH.SE to continue providing help to others in ways that I am qualified for. Seeing this done to Monica has me deciding to stay away.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - In light of the new mod removal/reinstatement process announced today, have you heard anything? Holding my breath here, honestly. I so much want this resolved in your favor. (aka anongoodnurse)

Comment: @medica I received email pointing me at the new processes and saying I can apply for reinstatement.  Having read the documents, I [will not do that because of serious fairness problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336236/162102).  I'll be putting up a new post tonight about the ongoing damage from the defamation, which they *must* address regardless of my moderator status.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - I'll be looking out for it. This won't just blow away. You have a tremendous amount of support from users and mods.

Comment: @medica That's just true. Monica may flag every action concerning herself, when originating from staff in recent *weeks*, as old&new CoC violation? "No bigotry!", bigotry: "obstinate and unreasonable attachment to a creed or opinion and intolerance of others," 1670s, from French bigoterie "sanctimoniousness," from bigot (see bigot)." Whether from staff, CoC itself, or those supporting it violently and with zeal, I seldom see anything that's not bigoted? It's just wrong on *all* levels, and I'm afraid it'll stay that way.

Comment: @medica https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336526/162102

Comment: Why was this unfeatured? Can we get this featured again?

Comment: @Salmononius2 featuring auto-expires after a month.  If you think it should remain featured you'll need to raise it with a moderator.

Comment: @Salmononius2 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281798/390967

Comment: Any positive updates?

Comment: @DonielF alas, continued ghosting from SE.  I've had to hire a lawyer. :-(

Comment: @yhyrcanus "Note for the non-Jews out there: The anti-negative (don't do the bad thing) rather than the positive (do the good thing) has Jewish roots", wait what? No, no, no! I can grand you that such texts may be in your religious writings, but this is claiming that your religion has invented morality, and that it did decidedly not do. No religion can or should make that claim.

Comment: @Maarten-reinstateMonica yeah you're right, that was poorly worded. I'll just say that there are a LOT more negative commandments in Halacha than positive ones.

Comment: Astonishingly bad behavior from StackExchange. This certainly changes my opinion of this organization.

Comment: The goat for Azazel was not a bride to Satan but to symbolically remove sin (ibn Ezra).

Comment: At the risk of sounding controvertial I would like to add a query here, which is this.

First off, I will say that I am "reading between the lines here" and coming to the conclusion that SO wanted to implement some new diversity policy (maybe something along the lines of trans and pronouns) and that you disagreed with this. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) Assuming that I am correct, I don't really see how you can say "racism is not acceptable, full stop". I am *not* saying I personally wish people to do racist things, but this seems like a free speech issue - and part of free speech surely includes the freedom to say racist things. It's an all or nothing situation - you can't just pick and choose the types of speech you want. If being racist *isn't* ok, then by the same logic it may be that refusing to use someones perfered pronouns *also isn't ok*.

Btw my sincere apologies if I misunderstood what happened here.

Comment: I thought I should add some additional context to my comment btw - I only make the above point because I personally feel that this whole debate we currently have around the freedom of speech issues has only occured because people began to say "you cannot do X" and "you cannot say Y"... It is not intended to be a controvertial point for the sake of controvercy, but I intended to make a broader point about how we came to be in such a situation. I hope I was not misunderstood.

Comment: What is the difference between revoking moderator status, and firing? What is the definition of firing? As a non-english native, I thought only employees could be fired from a company.

Comment: And exactly 4 years after your unfair firing Hamas started a surprise and brutal attack on Israel.

Answer (score 255):

I am appalled at this action by Stack Overflow, Inc. I urge them to reconsider, as this community, and I'm sure others, are significantly better places thanks to your past and ongoing impact. It's too late to wash this painful act from our memories, but it really needn't be too late to reverse its technical effects. I hope that if SO do offer to reinstate you as a Mi Yodeya moderator, that you'll continue here in that role, for the good of this community. If they don't, that will be, in my opinion, an ill-advised confirmation of a harmful decision.

Comment: Although I usually express agreement on Meta with merely an upvote (and I did so here), I'm allowing myself to also comment indicating my agreement this time, lest onlookers incorrectly think that a fellow moderator's not answering indicates something it does not.

Comment: Although I don't frequent Mi Yodeia as often as I used to, I well remember Monica's helpful participation in the forum. I'm registering my protest here in the comments and pray this will be resolved in the near future.

Answer (score 146):

I am shocked to read this. In nearly 4 years on MiYodeya I can only remember positive interventions from your side, welcoming new users, taking time to explain the site features, intervening in a highly balanced way whenever required, and generally acting as a force for good.

I cannot believe that anyone would see you as anything else than a highly positive contributor to the sites you helped moderate, and know you invested much time, energy and care to spur usage and elicit high-quality content on the sites you participated in.

I do hope this decision will quickly get reversed, and that you can go back to contribute as a moderator. No matter what, all the people you positively touched should in themselves be a reward for your investment.

In the end, *gam zu l'tovah* (a Jewish expression meaning: "this too will be for the best/may good things come out of this").

Answer (score 113):

Monica, for all we both have fairly broad interests, they don't seem to overlap much. But the fact that you're a very level-headed and nice person is impossible to miss even without many direct conversations. Many times you had a nice word in situations where I would just have grunted, walked away or sent the other person off. You were the moderator that we all aspired to be, or should have.

It has been an honor to serve with you. Regardless of what happens next, thank you for everything you've done here.

Comment: Thank you for these words and for all that you have done for your communities.  We didn't interact much, but I can see that you act with integrity, an important quality we should all strive for.

Answer (score 92):

To whom it may concern at StackOverflow, Inc.:

This is not about whether Monica was correct or not regarding her position on the matter at hand. This is about how you responded. Your [non-apology](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/) states that you (whether you personally or SE or whoever) "removed a moderator for repeatedly violating our existing Code of Conduct and being unwilling to accept our CM’s repeated requests to change their behavior," with [no evidence](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334248/an-update-to-our-community-and-an-apology?cb=1#comment1092882_334248) to support this. All you apologized for was "shipping" on a Friday afternoon – an extremely condescending way to respond to a fellow human being, by the way – not for what actually happened. You have the courtesy to say you're ["sorry to see [other mods resigning in protest] go,"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/389908) but to Monica you refuse to apologize and just stop short of saying "good riddance." Sara, I'll judge you favorably that you're just the messenger and it's not your message, but you should at least be ashamed that you had to deliver it. Certainly whoever gave the instruction should be ashamed of doing so.

Consider [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318630/) from not even a year ago when Monica was appointed moderator at Meta.SE:

> Monica is an experienced moderator across the Stack Exchange network and we thought it would be presumptuous to ask her to step up yet again; that was a little short-sighted of us because she's been rocking it here and has the cycles to come on board.
>
> These folks have quite a bit of moderation experience, some since <strike>the dawn of time</strike> the concept of pro-tem moderation itself. All of these individuals have been leaders on their respective sites, as well as leaders in the broader Stack Exchange moderator community. They're fair, even-keeled and most importantly, they're incredibly great at disagreeing with Stack Exchange!

You sing her praises, *including that she disagrees with SE*, yet when she disagrees with SE, you fire her?

While we're talking about that Meta post, consider this quote from a few paragraphs further:

> Everyone that works at Stack Exchange is *very* passionate about what they do, which leads to *very* passionate discussions especially where there's criticism involved. Sometimes, ***we*** as employees need to disengage, or dial it back, or whatever euphemism you want to use for *calm the heck down and think about the goals and the people helping you meet them.*

Even now you can still "think about the goals and the people helping you meet them" – and reconsider those goals, too!

What's striking to me about all of this, as I alluded to earlier, is how cold you all were in doing this, and how quiet you've been since. Where's your passion for what you do, especially given all of the criticism involved?

> Our appointed moderators will have ***full*** agency to correct any chain of correspondence that appears to be going off the rails, no matter *who* was originally driving the train. Sometimes it's better to let an objective party step in and handle things, we'll just leave it at that.

Shouldn't the same measure with which you expect moderators deal with the community be applied to the moderators themselves? Why was there no objective party involved in this decision?

For that matter, [why was the mod action review process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157258/) not heeded? If the other mods on the site(s) are to be brought into the discussion, by my count 21 separate moderators should have received emails related to this incident. I'd have thought that if they had, they'd have mentioned that alongside their support and their recollections of the TL transcript.

You might want to take a cue from [Abby's statement here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334052/) about constructive conflict:

> I think as long as everyone is operating from a place of assuming good intentions, good faith on the part of the other person. So you know, I'm not fighting with you, because I think you're a dingbat who's trying to ruin the site. I'm in conflict with you, because we both really care deeply, but have different ideas about what could be useful here. I think that is a productive conflict. As soon as you get to a point where, you know, you've you've flipped the bozo bit on the other party in the conflict, or you think, you know, this is an evil person, and I have to vanquish them, to trounce them, vanquish this evil, then it gets a little less, less productive, less constructive there. But I think it can be really, really healthy for a community.

How timely.

Now, I obviously wasn't there when everything went down, but if [this account](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5200/) is accurate, where was the assumption of good intentions and good faith here? That was a scarily quick leap to "this is an evil person, and I have to vanquish them, to trounce them, vanquish this evil."

---

To conclude on a more positive note: Monica, as I've said before, thank you for all you have done as a moderator here and elsewhere, and may you be reinstated quickly to be able to continue helping these communities as you have done so well in the past. As I [commented on the OP](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5193/stack-overflow-inc-sinat-chinam-and-the-goat-for-azazel#comment16235_5193):

> Of all the people for this to possibly happen to, you are the absolute last person who I’d suspect of abusing mod privileges. You’ve been nothing but helpful and kind in your interactions on SE [...] I can’t believe this would happen, and know that you have our full support.

I'd like to further commend you for your incredible patience and calmness with which you approach this (at least publicly). You [know where your priorities lie](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334282/publish-a-procedure-for-reinstating-a-removed-moderator#comment1093268_334282), and you're somehow able to keep a clear head during all of this. I specifically did not post this immediately, because I knew that if I did, this would be significantly more charged than it already is.

Chazal tell us that a mighty person is one who is able to conquer his inclination (Avos 4:1), and that being slow to anger is a prerequisite to acquiring Torah knowledge (Avos 6:6). They teach that Hashem is slow to anger both to the deserving and undeserving (Eruvin 22a et. al.), and we are commanded to emulate Hashem's attributes (Shabbos 133b). Hashem treats us the way we treat others (Sotah 1:9, which [you yourself learned for the Siyum](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/)); may Hashem reward your patience by having mercy on you during this Rosh Hashanah and Yom Kippur season.

Comment: I love that this answer comes with sources!  *Yasher koach*!

Comment: @Monica On a site like this, how could I not? And I believe *I* should be the one telling *you* teyasher kochaich. (I think that's the grammatically correct phrasing, anyway.)

Comment: @DonielF IINM, the verb applies to the noun כח and therefore is always in the masculine: יישר.

Comment: @DonielF the company is unlikely to read this here; did you also send it to them directly?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, as if they’ll actually read it there either. I thought filing it under “appeal a code of conduct violation” was appropriate.

Comment: Nice!  I should do that too.

Answer (score 57):

Writing from the Western US where the holiday has not yet begun.  L'Shana Tova to you all.

I have been very lucky to serve alongside Monica for a brief time as moderators for Writing.SE.  She has been an amazing mentor, not just for me but for other moderators, and always generous with her time and knowledge.

I actually agree with the new SE policy for mods and I'm a huge champion of diversity of all kinds.  But the way SE has treated Monica (and by extension, all SE moderators) is appalling.  They had an opportunity to carry out this process with respect and they failed on multiple levels, multiple times.

They don't seem to understand that treating a respected, hard-working, and experienced moderator worse than they'd allow any of us to treat a SE user spouting bigotry casts a pall over SE and shocks us all.

This is still fixable.  They can turn her "firing" into a suspension and work on communicating the new policy and all its ramifications to every mod, not just to the one who spoke out (one who never violated it or even opposes it in spirit).

It's a good policy aimed at supporting moderators who have felt unsupported by SE.  Scapegoating Monica is not going to help those moderators.  It's not going to help other moderators feel safe (I sure don't anymore).  And it doesn't help the community who has now lost at least 10 valuable moderators.

Answer (score 40):

As a Christian I am now consider if I will every surport stackoverflow again, as freedom of speach and religion is important to me.

---

I have now written an answer on another question, outlining how keeping to what one groups says is their **absolute and unquestionably right** to enforce on me is not compactable with my right to chose to be a Christian.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334636/132223

Update Sat 12th Oct.

The above linked answer has now been deleted by a staff member of StackOverflow as being offence, I will let people with enough rep to see a deleted answer decide for themselfs.

Comment: Totally agree, I'm a mod on Christianity StackExchange, this has seemingly had a chilling effect on our minute (compared to StackOverflow) userbase as the last 3 days have been mainly community bumped posts.   I don't think many of our users can abite a code of conduct that discounts individual consciences in favor of liberal ideology.

Comment: @PeterTurner It's not even liberal ideology. I'm a liberal and am _apalled_ by this behavior. This is some extreme left-wing nonsense, just as bad as extreme right-wing nonsense. Extremist views should not be the policy of a site like this. Sara Chipps appears to be the one responsible. I'm calling for Stack Exchange to fire her immediately for extremist, intolerant behavior.

Answer (score 34):

I see here two mutually exclusive accounts of what happened.  Someone is lying and I find it hard to believe it’s Monica.  If I get booted off the site for saying so, that only relieves me of the difficult decision whether to delete my accounts or not.  (And in response to the puzzling comment, if I do so, it will be because like others, I choose not to support the draconian behavior.)

Answer (score 34):

I senior mod on another site with about the same reach as SE, so I've a bit more experience of these situations.

SE is nominally, a site that pays great respect for its community, including its volunteer mods. That respect seems to be missing here.  The most up to date communication seems to be @Sara_Cripps reply to this thread, and frankly, if one of our mods wrote that to a community, there would be an uproar. As there has been on Stack Exchange. As there should be.

As this is a meta post, I hope it's okay to explain why.

> We understand there are some folks upset about this decision.

Well, yes. And those people aren't posting because they want platitudes, or to hear tumbleweed. Engage them!

> We aren’t going to share specifics out of respect for all individuals involved but this is a site reaching millions of people and we have to do what we believe fosters a spirit of inclusion and respect.

On a community site, if you find yourself asserting community standards *to the community itself*, and they're almost unanimously saying that you are wrong, then the odds are extremely high that that's how it is. The community themselves love inclusion. If Monica had bee  lacking in terms of "inclusion and respect", you can bet there would be people saying so and arguing between themselves here.

Do you see that? No, you don't. Nor do any users.

**Which makes it very very likely that Stack Exchange (the corporate side) is in the wrong here.**

What this post did, was effectively splaining. Telling this rather mature and huge community of experiences SE-ers,   whether it should feel community standards were kept. Well, the community feels SE has itself not acted in keeping with these standards. It's skeptical and asked for info to check those standards, with almost no dissenting voice.

I'd listen to them. Because from here, as a highly experienced mod of another site with an outreach in the 400m+ figure, I'm seeing a big difference between the talk, and the walk. Others might be seeing it that way too....

> When a moderator violates that, we will always do our best to resolve it with them privately. When we can’t we must take action.

And if you get feedback it was incorrect, you "must" do something to reconsider.

> This is always done based on what we believe is best for all SE users.

Well....

Maybe if "all SE users", or those you and the community trust, are unanimously telling you that it probably is very far from the best, perhaps you should stop. Listen to them. Reconsider. Don't just drop platitudes and 'splain to the community what it feels.

Please SE. This is my first ever post on a mod related topic. I wish it didn't have to be one like this. But I can't stay quiet either. It feels very wrong, and I'd like you to trust the community as SE professes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 24):

Monica, I signed in after a good few months of inactivity just to shockingly voice my disappointment at this whole situation (I only learned of it from the sidebar on SO). I cannot recall a single interaction in which you were not the voice of reason and sensitivity at the same time. Mi Yodeya and Stack Exchange as a whole are a less friendly corner of the internet without your moderation.

(Going back into my cave again now. Still hope to be back someday.)

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/what-if-your-orthodox-rabbi-tells-you-to-ask-your-question-on-mi-yodeya/3487#comment10304_3486

Answer (score 22):

I debated whether to make this a comment, or even send a brief message via your personal blog ... but decided a brief "answer" suited best. I hope that's OK.

While reading Schechter's venerable *Aspects of Rabbinic Theology*, I ran across his citation of [*Avodah Zarah* 5b](https://www.sefaria.org/Avodah_Zarah.5b.3?lang=bi&lang2=en), which includes:

> אשריהם ישראל בזמן שעוסקין בתורה ובגמילות חסדים יצרם מסור בידם ואין הם מסורים ביד יצרם
>
> ... Happy are you Israel; when they engage in Torah [study] and in acts of kindness, their [evil] inclination is given over to them, and they are not given over to their [evil] inclination. ...

It seems to me, Monica, that your actions through this *debacle* exemplify this saying. Personally, I've learned from your Torah study, and been touched by your acts of kindness. Keep pushing back darkness!

!אלפי תודות

Answer (score 20):

I [felt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372150/1593077) the writing was on the wall for this kind of upper-echelon behavior when I first saw the Code of Conduct. I am entirely unsurprised that something like this would happen, and it seems to be in keeping with a sort of a trend in various organizational settings in the US recently.

Answer (score 8):

Woa, Ididn't know why you were gone Monica. I miss you a lot.
Reading what happened I feel sure it must be for something good in future for you because as so many others here have written, you are the best moderator on any site I've ever known.

I'm so happy to have been able to read what you wrote here.
Thank you for making my corner of the world a little brighter on MY for all these years.

Answer (score 2):

You have been made an 'example of'! It happens, generally, when big money comes in from 'special interest groups'.

Comment: `'special interest groups'` What is it?

Comment: Please search in Google 'special interest groups' and you will be able to get a good explanation.

Comment: @Mr.deSilva What proof do you have that some conspiratorial “special interest groups” are at play here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry this happened to you. It feels like you were targeted and I would certainly wonder why. A lawsuit seems viable in your case. They deserve to be sued. They earned it. If you did sue, I hope you got some recompense from SO, the corporation.