# Catalog of sci-fi questions

Tags: discussion, question-catalog

We've had a bunch of questions of varying quality related to science fiction (or, more generally, speculative fiction), most or all asking how Jewish law would deal with some scenario that is either not currently practical or never could be.

This includes anything to do with space travel, even though it is something humans (including Jewish ones!) have done, since it's still practically out of reach for the vast majority of people and therefore the subject of a great deal of science fiction literature.

Let's make a list of all such questions that are at all valuable.

Comment: In light of this list, should we make a [scifi] tag?

Comment: @DonielF, tags are generally meant to describe the topic in the question that Judaism relates to. Sci-fi is more of an outside interest group that might be interested in a certain subset of our questions, cutting across different realms with respect to Judaism, so I see it as better served with a catalog like this than with a tag.

Comment: @DonielF I do not object.

Answer (score 11):

## Space Travel

### Issues with the Journey

[Mission to Mars: halachic challenges](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30683/mission-to-mars-halachic-challenges)

[Does the Torah prohibit leaving Earth?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64985/does-the-torah-prohibit-leaving-earth)

[Does one wash his hands upon waking up from cryostasis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101022/cryostasis) (UNANSWERED)

### Does Halacha Apply in Space?

[Teshuva that halachot don't apply off of earth](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73457/teshuva-that-halachot-dont-apply-off-of-earth)

[What defines "on this earth" from a halachic standpoint?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27107/what-defines-on-this-earth-from-a-halachic-standpoint)

### Space Burial

[Can a Jew who dies on Mars be buried there?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55941/can-a-jew-who-dies-on-mars-be-buried-there)

[Burial in Space](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38927/burial-in-space)

### Zemanim and Calendar Issues

[A Jew is born in space. What time rules does he follow?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55284/a-jew-is-born-in-space-what-time-rules-does-he-follow) (UNANSWERED)

[When does somebody living in space (e.g. ISS) observe Shabbat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9250/when-does-somebody-living-in-space-e-g-iss-observe-shabbat)

[Shabbat with time dilation in space](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38883/shabbat-with-time-dilation-in-space)

[Time dilation and waiting between meat and milk](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18530/time-dilation-and-waiting-between-meat-and-milk)

[Shmittah in Space](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/73473/shmittah-in-space)

### Aliens and Space Animals

[Would a space fish be kosher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55117/would-a-space-fish-be-kosher)

[Is there any reason to deny aliens according to Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43835/is-there-any-reason-to-deny-aliens)

[Does the Torah discuss aliens?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9197/does-the-torah-discuss-aliens)

[Can an Alien convert to Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/can-an-alien-convert-to-judaism)

[Extraterrestrial Sacrifices](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/59468/extraterrestrial-sacrifices)

[Would a non-kosher Earth animal born in space be kosher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64458/would-a-non-kosher-earth-animal-born-in-space-be-kosher) (UNANSWERED)

[Why don't Jews accept Our Lord and Savior?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55237/why-dont-jews-accept-our-lord-and-savior) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

### Space Objects

[Sending a Torah to the Moon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38583/sending-a-torah-to-the-moon)

[What is the halachic status of things in outer space?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/22133/what-is-the-halachic-status-of-things-in-outer-space)

### Berachos and Davening

[Would you need to make a bracha on a rainbow seen on another planet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77895/would-you-need-to-make-a-bracha-on-a-rainbow-seen-on-another-planet) (UNANSWERED)

[Which way to face while praying on another planet](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/91656/which-way-to-face-while-praying-on-another-planet)

[Should a person observe Rosh Hodesh & say "Kiddush Ha'Aretz" if he lives permanently on the moon?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55267/should-a-person-observe-rosh-hodesh-say-kiddush-haaretz-if-he-lives-permane)

[When and how often would someone say Kiddush Levana (Blessing for the moon) if he were on another planet?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65874/when-and-how-often-would-someone-say-kiddush-levana-blessing-for-the-moon-if-h)

Answer (score 1):

## Monsters and Fantasy Creatures

[Are Synagogues "holy ground," offering protection from evil creatures?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61619/are-synagogues-holy-ground-offering-protection-from-evil-creatures)

[PTIJ: Kiddushin by dragonslaying?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/111684/) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

### Altering Genetics

[Is altering human genetics wrong in Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64014/is-altering-human-genetics-wrong-in-judaism)

### Mermaids

[Would a mermaid be kosher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53216/would-a-mermaid-be-kosher)

[So where are these mermaids?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53255/so-where-are-these-mermaids)

[Status of a human-mermaid offspring](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80944/status-of-a-human-mermaid-offspring)

### Dinosaurs

[Is it acceptable under kashrut to eat tyrannosauridae meat?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50293/is-it-acceptable-under-kashrut-to-eat-tyrannosauridae-meat)

### Artificial Lifeforms

[Can Frankenstein's Golem wear women's clothing on Purim?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55521/can-frankensteins-golem-wear-womens-clothing-on-purim) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[Animals Created By Sefer Yetzirah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34932/animals-created-by-sefer-yetzirah)

[sefer Yetzirah ox goring,or Golem damages](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/34951/sefer-yetzirah-ox-goring-or-golem-damages)

[Can a Gentile create a Golem?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96396/can-a-gentile-create-a-golem) (UNANSWERED)

[Creating things with the Sefer Yetzira?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77727/creating-things-with-the-sefer-yetzira)

[How Kabbalistically accurate is the golem-making procedure described in "Niflaos Maharal"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2899/how-kabbalistically-accurate-is-the-golem-making-procedure-described-in-niflaos)

[Is a "Golem" the same thing as a person created through Sefer Yetzirah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21981/is-a-golem-the-same-thing-as-a-person-created-through-sefer-yetzirah)

[Was there a GOLEM?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16236/was-there-a-golem)

### Vampires

[Are there any Jewish sources that discuss vampires?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26593/are-there-any-jewish-sources-that-discuss-vampires)

[PTIJ: How can I halachically kill a vampire?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100608/how-can-i-halachically-kill-a-vampire) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

### Werewolves

[How should a werewolf celebrate Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55524/how-should-a-werewolf-celebrate-pesach) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[Werewolf in the Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5687/werewolf-in-the-torah)

### Zombies

[Surviving the zombie apocalypse?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26237/surviving-the-zombie-apocalypse) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[Suicide to prevent Zombification](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69518/suicide-to-prevent-zombification)

### The Hulk

[PTIJ: The Hulk & the principle of "כל דאלים גבר" (ie "whoever is stronger prevails")](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100768/hulk-whoever-is-stronger-prevails) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[Would a theoretical Hulk be allowed to transform on Shabbos?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101021/hulk-transform-shabbos) (UNANSWERED)

### Fairy Tale Characters

[PTIJ: Is Peter Pan forever Patur from Mitzvahs?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111740/ptij-is-peter-pan-forever-patur-from-mitzvahs) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[PTIJ: Issues with Pinocchio in Halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111738/ptij-issues-with-pinocchio-in-halacha) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[PTIJ: Rapunzel covering her hair](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111739/ptij-rapunzel-covering-her-hair) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

Answer (score 1):

## Quantum Physics

### Time Travel

[Time Travel and Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8496/time-travel-and-judaism)

[Would time travel be assur/mutar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23408/would-time-travel-be-assur-mutar)

[If you travel back in time, would you be obligated in Mitzvot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55661/if-you-travel-back-in-time-would-you-be-obligated-in-mitzvot)

[Are there examples of backward time travel in the talmud and/or midrash?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/77178/are-there-examples-of-backward-time-travel-in-the-talmud-and-or-midrash)

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101268/

[Can one go back in time to complete a minyan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80331/) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[PTIJ: Joseph and the time machine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/111638/) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

### Schrödinger's Cat and Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle

[Schrödinger's cat and yibbum](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40367/schr%C3%B6dingers-cat-and-yibbum)

[Can a person (or cat) be both alive and dead at the same time? (Schrödinger's paradox)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50887/can-a-person-or-cat-be-both-alive-and-dead-at-the-same-time)

[Poisoning Achashverosh if an Atom Decays](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69313/poisoning-achashverosh-if-an-atom-decays/) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[Reconciling the evidence for the Uncertainty Principle with belief in an omniscient G-d](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9735/reconciling-the-evidence-for-the-uncertainty-principle-with-belief-in-an-omnisci)

[Would teleportation be allowed?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/108504/would-teleportation-be-allowed) (UNANSWERED)

[PTIJ: Is Schrödinger's cat inscribed in the book of Life and the book of Death?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111728/ptij-is-schr%C3%B6dingers-cat-inscribed-in-the-book-of-life-and-the-book-of-death) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

Answer (score 1):

## The Singularity

### Cyborgs

[Would whole brain emulation be compatible with Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38123/whole-brain-emulation)

### Artificial Intelligence

[PTIJ: Should I worry about AI (Artificial Intelligence) taking over?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101030/should-i-worry-about-ai-taking-over) ([PURIM TORAH](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/))

[Is AGI possible according to Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87099/is-agi-possible-according-to-judaism)

[Could this passage have any relevance to artificial intelligence?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68754/could-this-passage-have-any-relevance-to-artificial-intelligence)

[P'sak halacha by AI?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6008/psak-halacha-by-ai)

[Can a robot count in a minyan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90215/can-a-robot-count-in-a-minyan)

[Robot as a competent proxy?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7083/robot-as-a-competent-proxy)

[Does Robot = Golem?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6053/does-robot-golem)