# Community Promotion Ads - 2017

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It is a bit late into this new year, being that we're already in the second month, but we are now cycling the Community Promotion Ads for 2017!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for Jewish life and learning
- interesting in-site activities and events
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4205).

Answer (score 14):

[image: Sefaria: A Living Library of Jewish Text]

Comment: Copied from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3869/2

Answer (score 13):

[image: Visit HebrewBooks.org - 50,000 s'farim and counting]

Comment: Copied from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3877/2

Answer (score 8):

[image: Current Mi Yodeya bounties]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Download and print our booklets for the holidays.]

Comment: Copied from http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3884/2

Comment: We have seasonal variations for Pesach and the high holy days (see the edit history on the linked post), but not for Chanukah and Purim.  Anybody want to make those?  If so, let's talk in [chat].

Comment: @MonicaCellio Maybe in the meantime edit them all into this post's revision history (and then we can rollback to them at appropriate times)

Comment: Anyone want to make a nicer image for this? Wasn't this supposed to be a placeholder last year?

Comment: @Scimonster I'd love it if somebody made a nicer ad for these.  We have nice Pesach and HHD ads that we can swap in in their seasons, but this generic one is pretty basic and boring.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Follow our curated feed on Twitter!]

Comment: This is for the curated feed managed by Isaac. Borrowed from last year. http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3852/5151

Answer (score 6):

[image: Magically convert a citation into a link on Mi Yodeya.]

Comment: Borrowed from Isaac Moses' [post](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3357/5323) from 2015

Comment: Updated by Rish for the new image requirements: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35551210#35551210

Answer (score 4):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Yiddish Language]

Comment: Note: There weren't enough example questions or followers, so it was deleted. Let's see if this time it will survive!

Comment: Looks like the new one (the one you linked to here) is also dead :/

Comment: @Shokhet - gllrrp. I'm not sure whether it's worth starting again or no :/

Comment: I just have to say, Mith, you did a great job with de-escalating the situation [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36550585#36550585). I honestly didn't know what to do at that point, but this was a perfect way to defuse the conversation. This is the stuff of moderator diamonds; כל הכבוד :)

Comment: @Shokhet - thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

[image: Help build a site for Semitic Languages Q&A]

Comment: I used [this hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279601/162102) to post this ad.

Answer (score -1):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Literature]

Comment: That should link to the real site, not the Area51 proposal.

Comment: @MartinSchröder - [we haven't finished designing ads yet](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/395/lets-design-an-ad-for-our-site), so we're still running these Area 51 ads for now.

Comment: May I ask what relevance this has to the community that there's an ad for it?

Comment: @DonielF - Jews are famous for having a great affinity for books. We're the 'People of the Book'. And Jews read a lot. Soo...

Comment: @Mithrandir By that logic, there are so many [tag:mathematics]-related questions on here we should have a link to the Math.SE site. And there are so many [sci-fi](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3743/catalog-of-sci-fi-questions) questions we should have one for Sci-fi and Fantasy.

Comment: @DonielF - that's why there's the score of 6 thing. If the community doesn't think it's relevant enough, it won't vote for it (as it hasn't). It's only if enough people think that it's relevant that it'll be displayed. I gave them the chance; there's no requirement to vote for it.

Answer (score -5):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Keep in mind - there is your community's own community-run Twitter as well - feel free to skip over this one in favor of that one.