# Community Promotion Ads - 2018

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's almost February in 2018, which isn't supposed to be the proper time to cycle these, but for this year it'll be once again, so we'll be refreshing the **Community Promotion Ads** for this year now!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources for Jewish life and learning
- interesting in-site activities and events
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4485).

Comment: Since when can images only be allowed from imgur? [This ad](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4211/9682) was well-received last year but is now ineligible.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Visit HebrewBooks.org - 50,000 s'farim and counting]

Comment: Copied from https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4208/472.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Download and print our booklets for the holidays.]

Comment: Thanks to Keelam for the new art!  See the history from [last year's post](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4209/472) for seasonal variations for Pesach, Yamim Noraim, and Chanukah. (Still looking for a Purim-specific ad.)

Comment: We have seasonal ads for three of the four.  Would anybody like to make a Purim ad in the next few months?

Answer (score 7):

[image: Sefaria: A Living Library of Jewish Text]

Comment: Copied from https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4207/472.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Re-envisioning the way Torah can be studied and taught]

Comment: Was this ad produced by AlHaTorah? If not, maybe it'd be worth approaching them with an offer to publish a free ad if they'll provide a graphic per the specs. That's how we got the HebrewBooks and Sefaria ads.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, nope, I grabbed it off their website and made it into a stretched image...

Answer (score 3):

[image: See all questions with active bounties]

Answer (score -2):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting. Keep in mind - there is your community's own community-run Twitter as well - feel free to skip over this one in favor of that one