# Should we have a "Help Center"

Tags: feature-request, new-users, help-center

On Puzzling.SE they have a very clearly organized Help Center. They also have a large ad on the main page that redirects to the Help Center.

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help

Should we have something similar here?

Answer (score 6):

We do have a [help center](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help).

Whether there should be an ad for it on the main page is a separate question. You can propose community ads [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4485/1569).