# Mei Eimatai Kotvin et HaPurim Torah?

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

This is not Purim Torah.

Mi Yodeya policy on Purim Torah is described in this Meta post: [Purim Torah policy - Allowed, but regulated](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated)

One of the points is that Purim Torah may only be posted from Rosh Chodesh Adar, or, if there are two, R"C Adar Bet.

This seems to contradict the quote from the Mishnah, [Megillah 1:4](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Megillah.1.4?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all):

> אין בין אדר הראשון לאדר השני אלא קריאת המגילה ומתנות לאביונים
>
> There is no difference between Adar Alef and Adar Bet, except for the Reading of the Megillah and Gifts to the Poor.

In all seriousness, shouldn't Mi Yodeya follow this guideline?

Comment: Why would you expect this rule in the Mishna to apply to this contemporarily- and locally-invented policy?

Comment: I figured that halachic idea is applied in different, contemporary situations.

Comment: I love that a question about site policy in the 21st century is asked *and answered* based on the talmud. It just goes to show that אֵין כָּל-חָדָשׁ תַּחַת הַשָּׁמֶשׁ.‎

Answer (score 7):

The interpretation of the Gemara there (6b) is that according to Rabban Gamliel, whom the Halakha is in accordance with, that Mishna is written shorthand (חיסורא מחסרא) and should more fully be read:

> אין בין ארבעה עשר שבאדר הראשון לי"ד שבאדר השני אלא מקרא מגילה ומתנות
>   There is no difference between the 14th of Adar Alef and the 14th of Adar Bet, except for the Reading of the Megillah and Gifts [to the Poor].

Thus according to the accepted Halakha this wouldn't apply to Mi Yodeya's Purim Torah Policy.

Plus, Mi Yodyea isn't obligated to follow Halakha and designs its Purim Torah Policy based on purely pragmatic considerations (not too long and centered in the time leading up to Purim itself).

Comment: So maybe (ignoring your final point) PTIJ should be allowed on 14 Adar I

Comment: @Daniel Maybe too you should recite the Shir Shel Yom for [day of the week of 14 Adar II] on 14 Adar I? It's only discussing laws unique to that day.

Comment: And we will not read special parshas this month (we read Sheqalim at the end of the month, the Shabbat before Adar II) and they are mentioned elsewhere in Megillah (and follows Rav except in one aspect where it follows Shmuel - the actual parsha we read for Sheqalim)