# Modulo the Mods

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

[I'm told](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) the mods here are "msh210", "Monica Cellio" and "Double AA".

How do I calculate the equivalency classes defined by the congruence relation *a* (mod *p*) of *a* ∈ ℤ for *p* ∈ {"msh210", "MonicaCellio", "DoubleAA"}?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Explanation of the math: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28139614#28139614

Comment: We should reopen this and update it now that Isaac Moses is a mod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), as I understand it, produces what's left of the first operand after you've removed every available instance of the second operand from it.

Therefore, to compute ∀ *p* ∈ {"msh210", "MonicaCellio", "DoubleAA"}: *a* (mod *p*):

- Let מי(*a*) = ☢("https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/*a*"),
  where ☢ denotes retreival with a standard web browser, a is a, and *a* is *a*.
- Remove from מי(*a*) every vestige of the members of *p*, so elide all evidence of care for:

  - Clear, coherent writing, using the best possible words and punctuation, correctly
  - Humility and civility
  - Precise argument and backing up of one's assumptions

By anecdotal induction, we can prove that there are exactly two possible values of *a* (mod *p*):

- ∀ *a* ∈ [**Q**](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/448041/q): *a* (mod *p*) =
  "i no everything about Jewish stuff but 1 thing. Wat and y/ y not LOL???"
- ∀ *a* ∈ [**A**](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/448042/a): *a* (mod *p*) =
  "U luzer thats dum! teh anser is Yes I KNOW IT."

Therefore, we can conclude that mod the mods, there are exactly two equivalence classes, **Q** & **A**.

Comment: Two questions. First: why is the function called מ? Second: Isn't it true that ∀ a ∈ Q: מ(a) is the browser retrieval of an answer? That would mean `∀ a ∈ Q ∪ A: a (mod p) = "U luzer that's dum! teh anser is Yes I KNOW IT."`

Comment: @Daniel These are both left as exercises for the reader. In particular, try (2).

Comment: Consider updating this to account for the newest mod.

Answer (score 4):

[Like the months](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69065/1713), users on Mi Yodeya don't have names; they only have numbers. A user is defined by his or her user ID, and the user name is simply the Babylonian equivalent. The user IDs to which the names msh210, Monica Cellio, and DoubleAA refer are 170, 472, and 759 respectively.

Those numbers are the mods of Mi Yodeya. All users, posts, or comments whose IDs do not equal 0 (mod 170, 472, or 759) are caused by a known [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Comment: Can anyone whip a list of those users/posts?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lcm(759,170,472) wow we are almost relatively prime

Comment: @DoubleAA You *are* relatively prime. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=gcd(759,170,472), just not pairwise.

Comment: Consider updating this to account for the newest mod.