# Where can I get a mod hat?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

I understand that [mod hats](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28139030#28139030) are only intended for mods to have, but I was wondering if it would be possible for me to get one anyway?  Just like [Super Bowl rings are occasionally put up for sale](http://espn.go.com/nfl/story/_/id/13342007/william-refrigerator-perry-super-bowl-ring-being-sold-auction), perhaps mod hats are sometimes made available as well?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 10):

Look what I just found:

[image: ebay listing]

I contacted the seller to ask if the hat comes with Actual Mod Powers (TM), but have not yet received a reply.

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure you want one of those? According to [this newscast](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28103853#28103853), mod hats are diamond shaped. Now, a diamond is made up of two triangles. Who is (in)famous for wearing a triangle hat? Haman. So a moderator hat is two of Haman's hat.

[No offense to the mods. You guys aren't usually too Haman-like. :)]

Comment: *One* of those would be a Haman-hat, but fortunately the other is an offsetting anti-Haman hat, thus neutralizing the problem.

Comment: Actually what you’ve proven is that moderators are two Haman-like.

Comment: You better be careful as we wield binding offensive flags with impunity against all who question our anti-haman-hood!

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that within the chat conversation you placed as a link in your question, there was a math discussion about "modulus".

Mod, as you know, provides the remainder.

Thus, to locate a mod hat, collect all the hats worn by all moderators from all Stack Exchange sites. Divide that number by the number of hats worn by just the Mi Yodeya moderators. The remainder would be defined as a "mod hat".