# Should drinking be required before Purim Torah questions?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

I see some users have a hard time releasing their year-round seriousness before reviewing [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) questions (e.g., the first comment [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69114/where-did-mosess-successor-come-from-if-he-had-no-parents)).

Should we therefore require Yodeyans drink enough before such reviews

***ad d lo yodeya ben mi yodeya v mi lo yodeya*** ?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: @DanF I hope that, in the spirit of Purim, you will not mind me *picking on you* with my link above. If you do not like, I am happy to remove

Comment: Oh C'mon, if we knew where to *get* [golden calf ale](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69154/472) that would be easier, but sometimes we just have to use our imaginations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drnikgv is strongly encoruged b4 Puri Torah. Otherwise you Can't make goodm question like [that one](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36356/1713)

Answer (score 7):

They need to be Ad DeLo Yada' Bein [Main](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) le[Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/). In other words, they need to be colorblind.

Now, it is well known that when one's eyes are closed one can't tell the difference between colors. This is the source of the practice to take a short nap on Purim after using Mi Yodeya a bit more than one is used to (because of the Purim Torah).

Comment: Here I am, looking like a "patriarch," and I never understood why only men get confused on Purim, until DoubleAA expounded. As it says: "you only get color blindness if it's on all of the X-chromosomes of your life."