# My friend's halachic questions

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

So, umm, I've got this friend, you see. And this friend, he has some very case-specific and detailed halachic questions that he wants answers to. I, of course, don't need the answer to these questions for myself, and would never ask for p'sak. But can I ask for my friend?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Funnily enough, someone just now asked a case-specific detailed question for a friend, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69289/are-there-kabbalistic-sources-that-address-abnormal-sensitivity-to-smell

Answer (score 2):

**Absolutely**. Why wouldn't this be possible? Mi Yodeya was explicitly created with the idea that everyone should be able to get high-quality answers to any question on Judaism, no matter how detailed and personal they could be.

The slight complication, if you ask for a friend, is that halacha prohibits you from opening messages meant for him, as an extension of [the *cherem* of Rabbeinu Gershom](http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/halacha/Volume_5_Issue_17.pdf) not to read other people’s mail.

As such and following the ruling of Mi Yodeya’s rabbinic advisor (the Rim, [R' I Moses](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2/isaac-moses)), the latest release of Mi Yodeya includes a special feature in order to **Receive Answers Virtually**, following the injunction in [Pirkei Avot 1:6](http://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.1.6?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all)

> עֲשֵׂה לְךָ רַב
>   
> “Implement for yourself a RAV"

Every Mi Yodeya user should have one by default. So you should simply write your question [as clearly as possible](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), incl. any previous research you did on the topic, and then simply have your friend [ask his RAV](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi).

Comment: @IsaacMoses, the Rim, who would have known?

Comment: Better known as the _Chidushe Harim_.

Comment: I feel like either I missed your joke or you missed mine.

Comment: @Yez well a joke is not too funny if one has to explain it. I thought I got yours. You're asking for a psak and make it sounds like it's for a friend. MY of course would not allow that. I take the counterargument and say that it is possible ... just that you have to work through a Rav.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but only if your friend doesn't specifically tell you to ask the question for him. If he did, that would make you his  שליח - his messenger. There is a general rule:

שליח אדם כמותו - a man's messenger is like himself.

Since your friend is not allowed to ask a psak question, if you are his messenger, you are not allowed to ask the psak question for him.

Comment: But אין שליח לדבר עבירה