# Why would you suggest asking post-Purim questions before Purim?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

Your Purim Torah policy says:

> Post Purim Torah questions between Rosh Chodesh Adar [Bet, if there is
> one] and a day or two after Purim, only.

That doesn't make much sense. Why would you want people to ask questions about what happens after Purim (your policy says **post** Purim) before Purim? All right, I see that you allow a day or two after Purim, but most of the time you suggest is before or during Purim.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

חכם עיניו בראשו. If you don't prepare for the post-Purim period, which can be a somewhat groggy period for some, beforehand, you'll have no hope of knowing what to do when the time comes!

For those emergency unforeseeable circumstances that one couldn't ask about beforehand, we allow the questions a day or even two days ([some people really go all out on Purim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36356/4794)) afterwards.

Comment: more like הרואה את הנולד