# Pesach related questions

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

The laws of Pesach suggest that one studies its laws starting 30 days before the holiday ("Starting from the day of Purim (which is thirty days before Passover), one should start teaching and learning the laws of the holiday. However, since the laws are available in print and everyone can learn it on his or her own, it is no longer customary to teach it so much publicly. Rather each one should review the laws on his own until they know it well." [From](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/260800/jewish/footnoteRef2a260800) Alter Rebbe's Shulchan Aruch 429:1).

As such, shouldn't there be a limited window on Pesach questions, the way that there are time limits on Purim questions?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I can't do it myself right now, but I'd heartily applaud a parody of the PTIJ policy in response to this.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that the Alter Rebbe's implication is that the laws of Pesach are already sufficiently available in text form. It therefore seems that any new questions about Pesach will automatically be duplicates. So we probably just shouldn't allow Pesach questions at all any more.