# Reopening Old Purim questions

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

After Adar, the practice is to close Purim Torah questions. I was just reviewing my review queue and 1 from last year came up. I don't know the mechanism for a question to be available for reopening so I don't know if there was any edit made or nomination presented that isolated this old question as viable for re-opening as opposed to any other old Purim question. I left it closed.

Is there a policy on reopening (at, and for the proper time) old Purim questions? Must a change have been made? Could ALL old Purim questions automatically be opened each year so that they can still be voted on and commented on?

Comment: Even old closed posts can be votes and commented on during ptij season. Closure just affects new answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Our [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/797/472) says:

> - If you want an old Purim Torah question re-opened during this year's season, ask the moderators.

Alternatively, you can use the reopen queue, as for any other closed question.  Which is what happened in this case -- an ordinary user nominated the question for reopening, which sent it to the review queue where you saw it.  A few others have been reopened that way, too.

There are now nearly 300 PTIJ questions.  There's no rule against reopening, but reopening (and then closing again at the end) is a one-at-a-time manual process, and most old questions have probably run their courses already, so the default is to leave them closed.

Comment: Is there any criterion which a reviewer should apply when deciding whether or not to endorse a reopening? How would a moderator decide?

Comment: I think, so far, moderators have granted all requests we've received.  Since our policy calls for deleting PTIJ questions that were closed for reasons other than being PTIJ, it's a reasonably safe bet that an old PTIJ question passed that filter. (Though I don't remember when we started the deletions, so some closed for other reasons might remain.) If you see something in the queue that you think, for whatever reason, really ought to be closed, I guess you should vote that way. I hadn't thought about that case; I saw the review queue as possibly faster than asking a mod, depending on timing.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The standards for PTIJ questions have changed over the years and many of the top-voted PTIJ questions would no longer be considered on topic even as PTIJ.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Long shot and I don't want to waste your or the other mods' time. But I would really love to dig up a PTIJ question I posted last year that was auto-deleted for lack of votes/low votes (I think it had a score of -1). It was called either "Creedmoor Hiskashrus" or "Creedmoorer Hiskashrus." It was one of my best questions and I'd like to try to make it better for this year. Can you help?

Comment: @SAH can you see this? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69685/472

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks! Awesome :). any chance it will be reopened or should I start anew?

Comment: @SAH I've undeleted and reopened it.   (Sorry, didn't realize that was a request for restoration and not just access.)  Edit away. (It won't appear on the front page until it's edited or answered.)

Comment: @mOnicacellio thanks!