# Purim Torah Emergency! Severely underutilized resource

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

It has come to my attention that there is [a German company](https://www.treif.de/treif/en/Home/) that makes *food-cutting equipment* of all things called ***TREIF***!

What's more, its [striking logo](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TREIF_Logo.jpg) is CC-licensed for reuse with modification, with attribution.

[image: TREIF logo]
<sup>["TREIF Logo," by Treif Marketing.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TREIF_Logo.jpg) Used with permission under CC BY-SA 4.0</sup>

From what I can tell using [Google Image Search](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi%3AAMhZZisEPXXok53PgbXtCwVGNVVHVsww_1XbQ7bG_1eR9t_1heyu7OqfZ3Nrw2lhxqJ6vkXBbTlOxQ7FbHPSyhs29GE5KkUj0qSlKQpoVvVZm3exwSoxLSzDmvNd3jmNOIEBdvI7dkwVSK1De3Bfkh1EO6BH0KuFAnwB7I3kGIzVadomrfGt5yWP-aMnHcNijaN_1HoMmKbXiDfoEtCQWxVbH8KSARBLKxA0xEDvsQMGxi75JAt_1q71t3oZOGK1d7RVikWUvkd9xQEqe_1f1oPx7H1jT14GiN869_1M-7ehU5UxXUh_1xx7Q8ueD11odUTCw8LthqoOrb4tpkLGq6pilLYEAWnse4MQ0HBMSlsM9gyyW7DIeU_1z7xWbooLSdosnmjwbeo8wBkr0YcC9_1n3YsvTFMkn88inuYxr5TMCOnlpHA6S4n-8zEMOxeOEuYJt74XfJRcSB1goECpQ1ryWUf0DJvP_1vXeuLIWxy85egX9IwapBlf3ytovs7RoG1Xh4SIFtoHa0wQRnIt7OZ-JNvIxCKeRYVR10_1uDcm69Lz0cbU_1aRjJwwbebCp4pja6MKkDLsz2SJsQ0-gUOqCmQIRWHVas124fp2xreiwApmtBTTN_1pA1DBgET11lpoWz1DM7EycLULb-5NddrLctn9QInfCN3axwd7mU0FO8gy7gxWTAzkapt7St_14m7kuV2ikfCbt0mmTS8gCcfAc1PbY4gTk3hMN2K_19Yqua0pnpsB6xqCjgQMEvOkxMEKWxwhQDPfQaM7z2JZbzJKk7hgmIw2NBec3et1vrpIaSxR3gQ7VYEvwjf1eNfsGdlWF49ShXBYCNfOKl7l8M8DUk6tQlZwqEbGjEyXH0LFmDpfoxqi1hI81LxRP_1iLwfz24h0YB-pErc2WlsC_1cCztEymopLOumHiUosb1pI8AezZULJv7oCQIK0ZJFLNJNgWQFFZM4QUeGtqCmkPLO-4YoMHHsKNUKlbaX8X_1RnpTQPrcRWsQ3O0RgfkD9--tUYgbwuQbBZXfhMcNCSEmHONvdsydwIMeaKBcDQTeZa6Uovdj40Odt-3Wkb1vC2V6knq3qPTA6RGQHnN-fPMeeQ-PS78Xx0sKAwBcsUdO4ewsvZtK1lv8m20Cwwf1mUUlLmcr0ms6uzxHLC4Hkdzw4e_1hwRdK84SkeRlhPK5_1jJtGJDV2gr3byprSaGvLZBe3qbjuNYzhOwEai-D2BadgXTMI3zrL_18t6t5srSIUENKDlQj8zvOzb8aGZOBEjjyp9UwOs8xMrahTR8mCHB368JMyFanvsB0_1R8zt5N5EFDtvnspAwmgcvDEJx4e1ufTxlUaOUxWwYUBKcCCO6BmB2nGXLMkVr-u3YoVQ2PXPMUC10OhqGea0wQ2LIjKB9CuEM6YQrjvytO7oVoNxNNtsY0ekEz0d5zVHr7dpr88TjCljxtmmAO6BpR8IPqnR5vTq31j5OKax6S7vph2dwrpk9fr1Smg4pa_1jin5-i9Z7pXuj0rctjqqClM01bbAOeNDc1PBAZmJGvK6NwTZLR699VaC2HpgZLUBFuV0GbSYUuVg665cJGjw&q=treif%20kosher&oq=treif%20kosher&gs_l=), this logo has not yet been used in online Purim Torah, despite the fact that it's been on Wikimedia since 2007.

The Jewish Internet has absolutely fallen down on the job.

Yodeyans, it is up to us to make sure that this company and logo are used in Purim Torah as well as possible, as soon as possible. This is not an opportunity to be either squandered or wasted. If I had a great idea off-hand, I'd write it up right now, but I don't, and I wouldn't waste this on just a cheap joke.

What should we do with this important resource before it's too late?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Maybe they're a subsidiary of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14951/759

Comment: Is this [meta-tag:meta-purim-torah-in-jest]?

Comment: @msh210 I was on the fence about that, but I think "not intended to be taken completely seriously" applies. What do you think?

Comment: (re precious comments) Seems like a serious question to me, but I defer to your judgement.

Comment: @msh210 I think the content itself is a little "precious." (Typo-jacking intentional.) If I take it out of M-PTIJ, it'd probably be irresponsible to keep the silly title and some of the tone, which is part of the point of it, I think.

Comment: I think posting this for the general public and asking for a quick response is the best way to get it wasted on a cheap joke.

Comment: @Yez Point taken. And yet, I think you may overestimate the readership of Meta.

Comment: @isaac I think even without the tag some silliness is allowed given Meta Is Different.

Answer (score 2):

Given that this logo is free to use, why stop with Purim Torah? We can use this logo for *real* good. Given the rampant spread of the crowd-sourced [O-Cmon](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14953/1713) *hechsher* "certifying" foods as kosher even though they're completely treif (c'mon, if the star-k won't certify your homemade *mishloach manot* it's obviously because there's bacon in them), it's about time we Jews fight back and start letting people know which foods are treif by affixing the "treif" logo. A few examples of things which we could start with include lettuce (which certainly contains bugs) and meat slaughtered by non-Hasidim.

Answer (score -2):

The question is if there is any advantage in labeling things Treif, as *anything* not certified can be assumed Treif anyways.

The practical difference is that if a piece of meat is Treif (colloquially - it really refers to a not-kosher species), one [may](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x4214) cook it in milk.