# Best answer contest: Second quarter of 5778

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is currently in the **Voting** phase.

1. **Nomination** - ending April 9, 2018

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Tevet - Adar, 5778 (from December 19, 2017 through March 16, 2018)** are eligible (yes, including [Purim Torah](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) answers).

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - April 9 - 16, 2018

   On April 9, this post will be edited to indicate that the Voting phase has begun, and the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag will be added.

   During this phase, everyone will be invited to vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on April 15, 2018. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: maybe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88753/759

Comment: Meanwhile, nominations for the [third quarter](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/best-answer-contest-third-quarter-of-5778) are open.

Comment: Locked to end voting.

Comment: Winner: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4610/best-answer-contest-winner-second-quarter-of-5778

Answer (score 6):

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/deviations-of-ralbag-from-normative-jewish-theology/88099#88099) to [Deviations of Ralbag from normative Jewish theology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/deviations-of-ralbag-from-normative-jewish-theology) by [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex) is one of the most comprehensive, clear, and well-sourced answers I have seen on this site.  I would like to nominate it, as it certainly deserves consideration for "Best Answer" this quarter.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90391/14850) to [Is there a halachic preference order to the grains used for matzot?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90390/is-there-a-halachic-preference-order-to-the-grains-used-for-matzot/90391#90391)

This is a topic that's becoming more relevant with the ever-increasing availability and awareness of non-wheat matzot, and I was happy that my research led me to write what I think is a clear and comprehensive answer.

[With thanks to Double AA whose comments helped me to direct my research and refine my answer.]

Answer (score 2):

Even though it's quite difficult to enter the competition after such a good answer by Alex, but still I would like to nominate [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90202/15256) regarding the customs of saying *Vihi noam.* I suppose most of us heard about this issue with the repetition, and even knew that it had to do something with a divine name, but I was looking for the answer for quite a while, and was really happy, when a local rabbi suggested me a good source that explained it in detail. I suppose it's worth your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate *my answer* to the question ["Bdikat Hametz: Enlisting multi-person team"](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/90237/bdikat-hametz-enlisting-multi-person-team/90239#90239) as the answer is a direct answer to the problem at hand. I was very pleased to find this issue addressed by the Tiferes Yisroel, and I'm sure others were also!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess I may as well join the throngs of self-nominators!

Of all of the ~200 answers I gave during this period (and some of them were pretty good), I would like to specifically nominate [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88035/16354) to [What was Yaakov's funeral procession doing in Transjordan?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/88029/what-was-yaakovs-funeral-procession-doing-in-transjordan), for the following reasons:

1. This question, asked by Joel K, was a self-answered question ("to share knowledge Q&A style"), and yet I still came up with some answers that the OP didn't, despite a very thorough answer that was already posted.
2. In his answer, Joel K noted that he hadn't found anyone who suggested that Ever Hayarden actually meant "Transjordan" in this case.  I found a number of commentaries who did so, and supported their theories very well, despite the obvious difficulties.
3. I researched and found support for 3 theories advanced in the comments (by Clint Eastwood, DonielF and Joel K, see comments to the question, and the discussion [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70871/discussion-between---and-joel-k))
4. I quoted Shu"t Terumas Hagoren in a question about Goren Haatad  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to nominate [Ezra's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89609/16354) to [PTIJ: Yeshivas Shem v'Ever](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89601/ptij-yeshivas-shem-vever), as it was simply hilarious, and inspired a few great comments as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was very pleased to come up with [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89475/2) to [What does Avot 6:6 mean when it invokes redemption?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/68802/what-does-avot-66-mean-when-it-invokes-redemption). As far as I can tell, it represents a novel way of interpreting the *beraita* in question, and I think it's genuinely plausible that it gets at ideas that Chazal were actually considering.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to nominate [msh210's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89552/16354) to [PTIJ - Who is Boris Karshina](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89548/ptij-who-is-boris-karshina).  I cannot remember laughing so hard the entire Purim Torah season, or ever accepting an answer so fast.  Shout out to Shalom for his comment there, as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to nominate [msh210's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89965/16354) to [PTIJ: Why all the obsession with BSD?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89954/ptij-why-all-the-obsession-with-bsd), which I (and at least 12 others) found so funny.

(Apologies to those not well versed in non- 'Microsoft and Apple' Operating Systems'...)