# Best answer contest: Fourth quarter of 5778

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Have you seen (or written) a recent answer on Mi Yodeya that you thought was really great? Let's have a contest to help you tell everyone about it!

This contest has two phases: Nomination and Voting. It is now over.

1. **Nomination** - ending September 17, 2018

   Post an answer to this Meta post containing a link to the Mi Yodeya answer you want to nominate. Answers created in **Tamuz - Elul, 5778 (from June 14, 2018 through September 9, 2018)** are eligible.

   Please link to one answer in each entry. Nominate as many answers as you like in separate answers to this post.

   *When you see a great answer, don't wait; post a link to it here before you forget!*

   Please *do not* vote on any answers to this post during the Nomination phase.
2. **Voting** - September 17 - 26, 2018

   On September 17, this post was edited to indicate that the Voting phase has begun, and the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) tag was added.

   During this phase, everyone is invited to vote on the answers to this post however you see fit. Upvote (or downvote, I guess) as many as you like.

[image: 300-point Bounty button]

The answer linked in the highest voted answer to this meta post will receive a bounty of 300 points after completion of the event on September 26, 2018. In case of a tie, the distinction will be shared, and the prize will be split.

---

<sup>Concept and words borrowed from [Movies.SE](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/rewards-for-the-best-answer-from-the-4th-quarter-of-2016).</sup>

Comment: If you see new great answers now, make sure to nominate them in the [5779 Q1 contest](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/best-answer-contest-first-quarter-of-5779)!

Comment: Locked to end voting. [Here's the winner.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4784/best-answer-contest-winner-fourth-quarter-of-5778)

Answer (score 6):

I would like to nominate [Alex's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93116/15256) to [Is it forbidden for a woman to learn Gemara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/is-it-forbidden-for-a-woman-to-learn-gemara) It is a very sensitive issue, yet he could still keep calm and give a lot of relevant sources to support his claim. In addition to listing these sources, he gave a really good summary and interpretation of the conflicting views.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to nominate [robev](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1739/robev)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/95052/472) to [Did King David's parents abandon him? (Psalm 27)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/95050/did-king-davids-parents-abandon-him-psalm-27). The answer presents a clear, thoroughly-researched, and carefully-footnoted explanation of a midrashic interpretation of the context for a puzzling passage.  The presentation in this answer goes beyond what I have come to expect from sourced answers (let alone others).

Answer (score 4):

I’d like to nominate Joel K’s [answer to where techias hameisim is alluded to in the Torah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93404/9682). It’s well detailed, in an easy-to-read format, that answers the question very well, albeit very lengthy.

Answer (score 4):

[Shalom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/21/shalom)'s [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93718/2) to [Can a woman divorce her husband and then convert to Judaism?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93716/can-a-woman-divorce-her-husband-and-then-convert-to-judaism) responded sensitively and informatively to a tricky "outsider"-type question. This was one of those cases where the asker had an inkling that there could be issues but didn't know enough about Judaism to ask about specifics. Shalom did a great job of thinking of and expressing what some of the major issues would be, all in service of a very-appropriate overall "ask a rabbi about your specific brand of this tricky situation" message.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate [Double AA's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93941/14850) to  my question [Does a pregnant or nursing woman fast on a postponed Tish'ah B'Av?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/93771/does-a-pregnant-or-nursing-woman-fast-on-a-postponed-tishah-bav) The answer is extremely comprehensive, well-structured and cogently argued.

Answer (score 3):

[mbloch's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93245/170) to "How can tzedakah to the needy of Israel be justified?" cites disparate secondary sources for a well-rounded answer.