# Best Answer Contest winners! Third quarter of 5778

Tags: discussion, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochachem* to the co-winners of the [Best Answer Contest for the third quarter of 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/vote-best-answer-contest-third-quarter-of-5778)!

Here are the original citations, submitted by [mbloch](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11501/mbloch) and [ezra](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11486/ezra), respectively:

- I was originally skeptical of self-nominations but the community seems to deal kindly with them. So allow me to nominate [my answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/92451/11501) to [Above ground burial](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/82886/11501) which took quite some research to answer a question I asked myself many times.

  That particular question was bumped up to the homepage the same day that I drove alongside such a cemetery pushing me to try and answer it.
- I'd like to nominate [רבות מחשבות's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90581/11486) to the question [Source and etymology of כפירה kefirah 'heresy'](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90573/11486). His answer is very concise and well sourced, getting straight to the point and answering the exact question of the OP.

The winning entries will split the 300-point bounty prize evenly.

[Best answer contest: Fourth quarter of 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4671/best-answer-contest-fourth-quarter-of-5778), covering Tamuz through Elul, 5778 (from June 14, 2018 through September 9, 2018), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please enter it!

Comment: Thanks a lot Isaac. Highly motivating to see the community’s appreciation

Comment: @mbloch ditto!  Thanks to everyone!