# Best Answer Contest winners! First quarter of 5779

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochachem* to [robev](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1739/robev), [Josh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97264/759), and [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex), the co-winners of the [Best Answer Contest for the first quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/best-answer-contest-first-quarter-of-5779)!

Here are the original citations, both submitted by [Double AA](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa):

> I nominate
>   [robev](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1739/robev)'s
>   [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/96596/759) to
>   [Differences between RaMbaM and RaMbaN's mitzvah count](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18009/759) which was asked on my
>   first day as a moderator. At the time I had considered closing the
>   question as Too Broad (or whatever that was called back then) since I
>   could imagine the "[question could be answered by an entire
>   book](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)".
>
> robev's post nearly proves me right, being so dense with information
>   and references he had to use a URL shortener to stay within SE's
>   30,000 (!) character limit. Well done on being thorough, robev!

and

> I nominate [Josh](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97264/759)'s and
>   [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/97301/759)'s answers to
>   [Number of Se'ifim in Shulchan Aruch](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/97160/759) to split the prize.
>   Those answers combined much original research with much fact checking
>   to provide a documented new piece of information for the internet.
>   They required much time, research, coding skills, and collaboration to
>   achieve their results. By checking results against each other and
>   against different editions they were able to get more done together
>   than alone.
>
> Nice work guys!

The winning entries will split the 300-point bounty prize, with half going to robev and the other half (or so) being split between Josh and Alex

[Best answer contest: Second quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4845/best-answer-contest-second-quarter-of-5779), covering  Tevet - Adar II, 5779 (from December 9, 2018 through April 5, 2019), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please nominate it!