# Best Answer Contest winner! Fourth quarter of 5778

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochacha* to [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex), the winner of the [Best Answer Contest for the fourth quarter of 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4671/best-answer-contest-fourth-quarter-of-5778)!

Here is the original citations, submitted by [Kazi bácsi](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15256/kazi-b%c3%a1csi):

> I would like to nominate [Alex's
>   answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/93116/15256) to [Is it
>   forbidden for a woman to learn
>   Gemara?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7071/is-it-forbidden-for-a-woman-to-learn-gemara)
>   It is a very sensitive issue, yet he could still keep calm and give a
>   lot of relevant sources to support his claim. In addition to listing
>   these sources, he gave a really good summary and interpretation of the
>   conflicting views.

The winning entry will receive the 300-point bounty prize.

[Best answer contest: First quarter of 5779](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4782/best-answer-contest-first-quarter-of-5779), covering  Tishrei - Kislev, 5779 (from September 10, 2018 through December 8, 2018), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please enter it!