# Best Answer Contest winner! Second quarter of 5778

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answer-contest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochacha* to [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex), the winner of the [Best Answer Contest for the second quarter of 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4456/best-answer-contest-second-quarter-of-5778?cb=1) (and the first Best Answer Contest winner without a tie)!

Here is the original citation submitted by רבות מחשבות:

> [This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/deviations-of-ralbag-from-normative-jewish-theology/88099#88099) to [Deviations of Ralbag from normative Jewish theology](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/86704/deviations-of-ralbag-from-normative-jewish-theology) by [Alex](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex) is one of the most comprehensive, clear, and well-sourced answers I have seen on this site.  I would like to nominate it, as it certainly deserves consideration for "Best Answer" this quarter.

The winning entry will be awarded a 300-point bounty.

[Best answer contest: Third quarter of 5778](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4577/best-answer-contest-third-quarter-of-5778), covering Nisan through Sivan, 5778 (from March 17, 2018 through June 13, 2018), is ***already underway***. If you see a new great answer, please enter it!