# PTIJ - Stopping Leitzanus

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

According to [Megillah 25b](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%91), which says:

> אמר רב נחמן כל ליצנותא אסירא בבר מליצנותא דעבודת כוכבים דשריא

do the Mods have an obligation to delete or block [Leitz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/14326/leitz) from Mi Yodeya?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that since [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89405/16354), Leitz discussed Avodah Zarah, he should be considered ליצנותא דעבודת כוכבים, and be allowed to stay.