# PTIJ: Why are so many Purim Torah posts on here not food related?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

This time of year, we all have a policy we call “Purim Torah Ingest.” As the name implies, we’re supposed to be eating these things.

As such, shouldn’t more of these be food related? Further, perhaps there are halachic issues of eating non-food Purim Torah, since it would get into issues of eating non-Kosher. (By extension, even food Torah has to be about Kosher food.)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

All the food related sheilos were already snatched up and ingested ;)

Comment: Next question: did they make a Bracha first?

Comment: i think they had to bentch after all of the _fuss_ haba bekisnin

Answer (score 0):

Around this time of the year, people eat an abundance of ha-**mahn**-tashen. Some people, like me, are particular about eating *mahn* (poppy seed) ha-mahn-tashen.

The *mahn* as you know, was the main food eaten in the desert. And regarding *mahn*, the Torah says it was the bread and we should get **full** from it.

So, everyone's focus has been filling themselves with ha-mahn-tashen - it's the only food people are interested in, now, and they're so full they can't think of discussing any other type of food. There's no reason to do that.

Comment: So why not have lots of jokes about that particular food, then?

Comment: @DonielF That's wasn't quite what you asked. But, there's a simple answer for that, anyway. They had they're fill with the mahn, already. And, as you know from *Bahalotcha*, they were getting bored with it. What, you want more boring questions?

Answer (score 0):

I think that quite enough of these are, in fact, food related.  See, for example:

[PTIJ: Is Super Mario Odyssey a Basar B'Chalav issue?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89463/ptij-is-super-mario-odyssey-a-basar-bchalav-issue)

[PTIJ: Why is there an inyan to eat Chinese food?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89396/ptij-why-is-there-an-inyan-to-eat-chinese-food)

[PTIJ: India is the size of an olive - so what?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89384/ptij-india-is-the-size-of-an-olive-so-what)

[PTIJ - Raui Leachilas Meraglim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89380/ptij-raui-leachilas-meraglim)

[PTIJ: How do I know if MiYodeya cookies are kosher? What should I do on Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89349/ptij-how-do-i-know-if-miyodeya-cookies-are-kosher-what-should-i-do-on-pesach)

[How were the Jews able to eat Haman?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80889/how-were-the-jews-able-to-eat-haman)

[PTIJ: What's wrong with my hamantashen?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/80869/ptij-whats-wrong-with-my-hamantashen)

Comment: What’s your source that slightly less than half of this year’s PTIJ is enough? If it was more, we could apply Rubo k’Kulo, but as it stands, this doesn’t seem to help anything.

Comment: No, it's that 1/3 should be Purim, 1/3 Torah, and 1/3 ingest, so the ratio is almost exactly correct.