# PTIJ: Is being mean to one's self against site policy?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

The end of the ["Be Nice" page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) says

> In summary, have fun, and be good to each other.

This implies that being good to one's self is not necessarily required.

I've noticed a certain user with a pattern of behavior of abusive remarks to himself.

Consider [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/69262/4794), in which he refers his own understanding, as the OP, as "silly."

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89392/4794), he attempts to swindle himself.

And in [this deleted answer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4517/4794), he actually goes so far as to call himself a fool and a nitwit!

Should something be done to censure this user, or are his actions within accepted site policy?

As an aside, that user is smelly.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).