# PTIJ: Worst Answer Contest winner! 5778

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

Congratulations and *Yeyasher Kochacha* to the winner of the Worst Answer Contest 5778!

Here is the original citation, submitted by msh210:

- I nominate the question: [Implications of Samoa skipping a Friday](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12760/170)

  Currently our [lowest-scoring](//stackoverflow.com/q/17218964) question, it has two major flaws:

  1. It refers to "the island of Samoa", when in fact Samoa comprises several islands. Although Isaiah (40:15) says "הֵן אִיִּים כַּדַּק יִטּוֹל / he'll take them islands as scant", it's clear from the context that the "he" is Mr. Mid'li and not our OP.
  2. The entire question is premised on the idea that "one cannot 'jump' into the middle of Shabbat". But the only support offered for that claim is a Mi Yodeya post about Australia. Besides the general unreliability of Mi Yodeya, there's the issue of the relevance of Australia to a question about Samoa. The two countries could scarcely be more different; as just one example, Australia gazes (Psalms 119:6, "Oz won't be shamed when it gazes") whereas Samoa listens (Deuteronomy 11:13, "it shall be that Samoa will listen").

The author of the winning entry will receive a 300-point bounty prize.

Worst Answer Contest: 5779, covering through Purim 5779, is ***not already underway***. If you see a new terrible answer, please wait to enter it!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).