# What should we do about this "derive pi from Torah" answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/94297/472) to "How the irrational number Pi can be derived from the Torah?" has been flagged several times in the months since it was posted.  (It has an outstanding flag now, again.)  It has a positive score (+18 / -5), so the community cannot cast delete votes.  There is a disagreement in the comments about whether it is an answer to the question.

The question asks, in part:

> In what way can the irrational and infinite number Pi be derived from the written Torah?

The answer is:

> Pi can be derived from the Torah by rolling up a Torah scroll and measuring the end's diameter and circumference. The ratio between them will be pi.

What action, if any, should we take?  ("None" is of course a possible answer.  I'm not advocating anything in this question; I'm asking a question for community discussion.)

Comment: Do we have a general policy on not-entirely-serious-answers? A perhaps similar example is [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13800/13438) which has [this comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13764/how-do-we-know-that-god-exists/13800#comment230359_13800) saying: *-1 IMO this reflects poorly on Judaism, that the top-voted answer to arguably the biggest question is a joke* (especially as the last paragraph was only edited in later).

Comment: @mbloch I would guess that the flags are about the fact that it clearly does not address the *intent* of the question.

Comment: I don't have an opinion on this answer one way or another, but I don't understand why a joke answer is allowed to stand while [a serious answer on the same question](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4736/1569) was twice deleted (apparently unilaterally by a moderator) for the reason that it was a joke, despite the author's protestations to the contrary

Comment: @ba The moderator in question did say in his answer to that Meta question that *Arguably it should be deleted too.*

Comment: Out of curiosity, what brings this up now? The answer has been up for six months now.

Comment: @DonielF an outstanding flag.

Comment: Interestingly, there is [an ongoing discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322769/this-coc-is-getting-out-of-control-its-eating-zombies-now) on meta.stackexchange.com about an answer with +195/-9 that was deleted because of flags. It's a different issue from the one with this answer but perhaps the general arguments there about deleting high scoring answers can be enlightening.