# PTIJ: CAN EVERYONE PLEASE STOP SCREAMING?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

I've recently been perusing some old questions, and it's come to my attention that users just have a habit of screaming an awful lot.

It's an [incessant amount of shouting](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70260/shofar-and-lulav-on-shabbos-how-can-rabbinical-decree-override-deorayso#comment202212_70260) on here, from [birthday wishes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7470/birthdays-in-judaism#comment252495_7470), to [warning about potential issurim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55328/why-didnt-jacob-shave-his-beard#comment145803_55328), to [site policy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5215/%D7%9E%D6%B8%D7%97%D6%B9%D7%94-%D7%90%D6%B6%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%97%D6%B6%D7%94-remez#comment33467_5215), to [howling](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55524/how-should-a-werewolf-celebrate-pesach#comment146602_55524), to [random interjections](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44543/did-avrahom-fail-the-test#comment116393_44543), and even a [long shpiel on the very topic of going deaf](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37468/). And don't get me started about the [Joke-a-thon ridiculousness](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4955/).

My head hurts so much from all this screaming I think I’m going to explode. As a PSA to the community, can we please stop screaming at each other? Otherwise I might have to take you all to Beis Din, as one is liable to pay damages for screaming and causing someone to go deaf (BK 85b).

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: YOU FIRST......

Comment: Not to mention when @Alex screams those Mishnayos from Soncino

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Gotta preserve the difference between Mishnah and Gemarah.

Comment: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5007/ptij-should-alex-give-up-his-best-answer-contest-and-answerathon-prizes#comment15704_5007