# PTIJ: Purim Torah in Tishrei

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

[As we know](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55200/), there is a Gezeira Shavah of

> פורים פורים מיום הכיפורים

As such, the same way that we have PTIJ from Rosh Chodesh Adar until just after Purim, shouldn't we have PTIJ from Rosh Chodesh Tishrei until just after Yom Kippur?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 1):

The reason we have Purim Torah all throughout Adar is because of the gemara that says משנכנס אדר מרבין בשמחה. Without that, we'd only have Purim Torah on... Purim. The gezeira shava you mentioned does not link Tishrei and Adar, it just links Purim and Yom Kippur. And since use of the computer for posting Purim Torah is forbidden on Yom Kippur itself, there is no date in Tishrei that's eligible for Purim Torah.

Comment: So, you're saying we should post...whatever the opposite of a joke is in Av?

Comment: @DonielF Well the gemara doesn't say to increase in sadness in Av. Just decrease in simcha. So we should post fewer jokes than usual. Since jokes are off-topic the rest of the year outside Adar, there's not really any way to do less.

Comment: Exactly - we should do so by posting "negative" jokes - hence, the opposite of a joke.

Comment: @DonielF Sounds like a good idea for a proposal.

Comment: @DonielF I think it might make more sense to enforce a rule requiring people to post less in Av than their usual average number of posts per month. Since learning Torah causes simcha.