# PTIJ: Should math questions be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

I don't mean questions about math as pertains to Judaism. I mean straight-up math questions, like anything you'd see on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com).

The reason I feel this way is based on the Mishnah (Avos 3:18, translation follows Tosfos Yom Tov):

> אמר ר׳ אלעזר חסמא קינים ופתחי נדה הן הן גופי הלכה תקופות וגמטריאות פרפראות לחכמה
>
> R’ Elazar Chisma said, “Bird-offerings and windows of Niddos are the body of Halacha; mathematics and geometry are appetizers for wisdom.”

Why is it so important? As Rabbeinu Yonah writes on this Mishnah:

> מפני שיש בהם חשבונות רבים וחכמת החשבון מחדדת את האדם:
>
> For they have many calculations, and the wisdom of mathematics sharpens a person.

Presumably he means that one should learn math, etc. in order to sharpen his mind, which he can then apply to Torah.

So it's a tremendous mitzvah to learn math, then! Why shouldn't it be allowed on-site?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: There is a non-Purim-Torah aspect to this question. It's really quite hard to define where the Rambam draws the line between Torah and other knowledge.