# PTIJ: How can we publicize falsehoods on our error and tour pages?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

On the [error 404 page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/error/404), we see the following text:

> If someone says I toiled but did not find, do not believe him. If he says I found but did not toil, do not believe him. If he says I toiled and I found, believe him. (Talmud, Megillah 6b)
>
> My apologies, I apparently didn’t toil hard enough to find the URL you asked for.

But consider the continuation of the Gemara:

> הני מילי בדברי תורה אבל במשא ומתן סייעתא הוא מן שמיא ולדברי תורה לא אמרן אלא לחדודי אבל לאוקמי גירסא סייעתא מן שמיא היא
>
> These words are by matters of Torah, but by business, it’s assistance granted by Heaven. And by matters of Torah it wasn’t said except [when one is] sharpening [his knowledge], but to uphold the reading, it’s assistance granted by Heaven.

Clearly, searching is a matter of business, as you’re buying information with your URL. Even if it’s Divrei Torah, obviously you’re looking for the page to review, as otherwise you wouldn’t know it existed that you’d be looking for it. Therefore, it must be that the error message is wrong; perhaps the site toiled as hard as it could, but Heaven didn’t help it.

It’s not just the error 404. Consider the [standard error message](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/error/):

> It’s not you, it’s us. **This is our fault.**

And

> We have erred.

Well, maybe it’s not your fault. Maybe I’m just intentionally plugging in a URL that causes an error. You liar.

Then there’s the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). As we see, [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10639/can-a-sukkah-have-all-glass-walls) is cited with 14 upvotes, no edits, and 2 answers, scoring +4 and a checkmark, and +3 respectively. On the *actual* page, as you can see, the question *actually* scores just +10, has a boatload of comments not cited on the tour, four answers, and the two answers cited actually have +14 instead of +4 (but it does still have the checkmark), and +8 instead of +3.

The author of the tour is clearly aware of this, as the +4 answer is later linked again, this time with +9. But no checkmark this time around. It also has an edit button, but no share or flag. The comment there (oh, right, comments exist on answers too; those weren’t there earlier) is accurate, but it doesn’t have the upvote it should.

Finally, at the bottom of the tour, we make the claim that

> Stack Exchange is a network of 174 Q&A sites just like [Mi Yodeya].

Uh, no it’s not. Is there any other site on SE that’s dedicated to Judaism? Clearly, the only thing we have in common with other SE sites is the domain name.

How can we claim to be a site for disseminating the truth about Judaism, when we seem to be disseminating so much falsehood?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).