# PTIJ: Whose heart is רבות in?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

I have a serious concern about one of our members.

As Shlomo HaMelech once said (Mishlei 19:21):

> רבות מחשבות בלב איש
>
> [רבות מחשבות](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/16354/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA) is in the heart of man.

I can’t imagine that’s a healthy situation for him. This is Pikuach Nefesh - does anyone know whose heart רבות is in so that we can rescue him?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Am I the only one who posts Meta PTIJ anymore?

Comment: I had an idea to make a best comment contest - PTIJ or not, feel free to run with that idea, please

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel I recommend against doing that non-PTIJ. Comments aren’t meant to be substantial; if they’re substantial enough to (somehow) reward their author, they should be made into proper answers. (Unless it’s a joke, in which case it *definitely* should be PTIJ.)

Comment: Ah yes, I only had good jokes in mind.

Comment: I was also going to ask questions about רבות מחשבות

Comment: @Daniel Great minds think alike. Must be the shared name.

Comment: Thank you, but no one pinged me about this.  I would assume that I would be most qualified to answer...

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I assumed you were too busy hanging out in someone’s heart to answer. I take it you made it out safe and sound?

Comment: @DonielF actually, much too busy at work this week. Baruch Hashem, the coming week should be lighter.

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100608/4794

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Talmud states ([מגילה דף יב](//www.sefaria.org.il/Megillah.12a.18)), a bare "איש" in Scripture refers to either Mordecai or Haman. I wouldn't suspect our רבות מחשבות of being in Haman's heart, heaven forfend, so he must be in Mordecai's. But the Talmud also states ([שבת דף פח](//www.sefaria.org.il/Shabbat.88a.5)) that in Mordecai's time the Jews re-accepted the Torah; surely it was [כאיש אחד בלב אחד](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Rashi_on_Exodus.19.2.2) like the first time, so Mordecai's heart is all Jews' hearts. Thus, רבות מחשבות is in all Jews' hearts. Thank God, רבות מחשבות has the same *gimatriya* (1364) as ניתוח להוציא רבות מלבבינו, a surgery to extract רבות from our hearts, so we should be okay.

Comment: Maybe he’s in Moshe’s heart (Berachos 54b), or Ulla’s or Rabbah Bar Bar Chanah’s (Pesachim 54a), or c”v Menasheh HaMelech (Sanhedrin 103a), or Noach (Sanhedrin 70b), or R’ Ze’ira (Yerushalmi Kiddushin 20a), or... L’chora your conclusion *has* to be correct, as we pasken like Erchin 15b that if we don’t know which of several things something refers to, we assume it means all of them.

Comment: I see he might even be in Hashem’s heart, as per Bereishis Rabbah 3:3.

Comment: Excellent. Better than I would have answered, at least.