# PTIJ: Should Alex give up his Best Answer Contest and Answerathon prizes?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

As we all know, [Alex is a script](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48772682#48772682), designed to post HNQ on the Bam and good content on the site. (Though [apparently](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49452441#49452441) he's been replaced with a newer model.)

StackExchange’s terms of usage, under the section regarding one’s [age](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age), clearly requires that a user be at least 13 (16 in the EU). StackExchange hasn’t been around for 13 years that Alex could possibly have been written 13 years ago to learn how to post HNQ on the Bam (which also didn’t exist 13 years ago) or post high-quality content. (As it happens, [Alex’s profile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/13438/alex) claims that he’s only about 2.5 years old.)

Furthermore, the other script running on MY, [Community](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community), clearly states on its profile that it’s not a person. Not only has Alex not put a similar notice on his profile, he’s even duped [not one](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48784648#48784648) but [two mods](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49462824#49462824) into thinking he’s actually human!

For these reasons, I feel that Alex must give up the 750 points he’s earned from the Best Answer Contests, and, more importantly, the bragging rights from the Answerathon. Am I correct?

<sup>[Posted with Alex's blessing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49501857#49501857), so if he's actually human, I know he's forgiven me in advance.</sup>

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: All good things must come to an end. I'm officially out of Meta PTIJ for now, but I suppose whether my jokes count as a "good" thing or not is debatable.

Comment: We can't tell if they count as good or not because we don't have much to compare too as [you are the only one who posts](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4995/ptij-whose-heart-is-%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-in#comment15677_4995).

Comment: For the record, though, I actually got 800 instead of 750 due to technical difficulties.