# PTIJ: how do I differentiate the Alexes in the Gemara?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

[רבי אלכסנדרי](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%99) is mentioned, per a sefaria search, about 30 or so times between the two gemaras.  I was wondering, however, which of the two Alexes this is referring to. There are two Alexes on this site of significant stature. Knowing the difference could help quote the Gemara better i.e. I’ll know who *actually* said what, and thus be able to say things בשם אומרו (Avos 6) more accurately. Of course, there are many such reasons one would want to procure such information, I presume.

---

## This question is [Meta Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Meta Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I’m not sure whether this is Meta or regular PTIJ

Comment: Pertains to the site.. @don

Comment: If you've read [The Lonely Man of Faith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lonely_Man_of_Faith) by R. Joseph B. Soloveitchik, you should be able to distinguish between Alex the first  and Alex the second.

Comment: @Alex Which one are you? :)

Comment: No doubt you are @Alex the second

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel What makes you think that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just ask your Amazon Echo. "Alexes? Which one is it?"