# Purim Torah Policy: Misinterpretation of Jewish *ideas* as well, or only Jewish texts?

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

I know PTIJ season is basically over, but what can I do, this is when the question was raised.

[PTIJ: Why do Jews eat filtered fish?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/101136/)

The joke, obviously, is misinterpreting "gefilte" as "filtered." That's not misinterpreting a Jewish text, but rather a Jewish *idea*.

[Some people](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101136/ptij-why-do-jews-eat-filtered-fish#comment337612_101136) seem to think that's an important line and therefore this is not PTIJ, while [others](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/101136/ptij-why-do-jews-eat-filtered-fish#comment337639_101136) think it's fine.

What's the official policy on this?

Comment: What is the Judaism idea represented by "gefilte"? [This](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/213/why-would-a-product-be-only-for-cooking-and-pureeing#comment109_214)?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Eating gefilte fish on Friday night is a minhag practiced by a large percentage of Jews

Comment: DonielF is *gefilte* fish, in particular, an expression of Judaism or of Jewish culture? Is it different from eating lox at bris meals?

Comment: @IsaacMoses To those with that minhag, they would argue that it’s an expression of their Judaism.

Comment: One could say the same about all kinds of expressions of the culinary culture of particular Jewish communities. Culture and religion get mixed up in people's minds. In many cases, the mix-up gets entrenched enough that it gets *minhag* status, but not in all. I'm aware of a *minhag* to eat fish on Friday night. Is there a minhag to eat lox and cream cheese at a bris? Is there a minhag to eat gefilte fish? Is there a minhag for cholent to have potatoes in it?

Comment: @DonielF (I moved the comment you are replying to, to the answer below). But the whole point of filtered :) fish is avoiding borer.

Comment: Purim Torah Policy questions are on topic on Meta all year. Don't worry about asking late in the season

Comment: Believe it or not, some people would consider the association of Jews with gefilte fish as a "racist" stereotype. Akin to assuming that all blacks eat watermelon. Personally not only am I not offended if someone assumed that about me and I don't quite follow what's racist about it. But, apparently, it is for many people.

Answer (score 7):

The [policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) states:

> So, post sincere-looking questions (you know, the kind that invite answers) that: ... misinterpret a real Torah concept or Jewish text ...

I can't speak for anyone else, but for me, the issue here is not whether Judaism ideas (i.e. "Torah concepts") are fair game for PTIJ fun, but whether "gefilte" is an expression of Judaism (and not just of Jewish culinary culture). If it is, playing with it is on-topic. If not, then it isn't.

Consider the following parallel examples, all of which I would consider off-topic (and, for the record, not funny):

- What kind of key do I need to open lox?
- Does cholent taste as good if pot is substituted for potatoes?
- Is everyone who goes to NYU impatient? The school's name sounds like "nu!"

Comment: It's because you "filter" out the bones, which is a halachic thing, not just a culinary thing. And it just so happens that it sounds like "gefilte". So it's a play on the halachic concept, not just the culinary culture.

Comment: @Ariel Your post does not indicate that whatsoever, and if that’s what you’re going for, it either should be posted on the Jokeathon, closed as a riddle question, or both.

Comment: The first is somewhat funny; the 2nd i s"cute" but weird. I don't like weed, but, I have to ask my friend if she's ever tried that recipe. The 3rd is a total loser question.