# Turning regular questions into PTIJs?

Tags: discussion, purim-torah-policy

I was about to ask a PTIJ when I discovered that the subject had already been covered as a serious topic with serious answers. However, I personally would like to hear the more humorous possibilities on the topic.

Is it okay to convert regular questions into PTIJs?

Comment: It's already been done in the opposite direction: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15059/1569 > https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15093/1569

Comment: @ba PTIJ policy has evolved over the years. Something happening in previous years does not mean it would have qualified today.

Comment: @DoubleAA I didn't say it did. But why should it not have qualified today? It was a good question (+13/-1)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated),

> So, post sincere-*looking* **questions** (you know, the kind that invite **answers**) that:
>
> - **misinterpret** a real **Torah** concept or Jewish text
>
> or
>
> - apply a distinctly **Torah** style (e.g. Talmudic analysis) to an **irrelevant** topic

By this standard, a valid non-PTIJ question is unlikely to qualify as a valid PTIJ question, since it's not deliberately misinterpreting something real or apply a Torah style to an irrelevant topic.

Comment: The topic I was planning on asking about was "can aliens convert to Judaism", which is covered here: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17108/can-an-alien-convert-to-judaism?r=Search Results  - and yeah, I would've deliberately misinterpreted something for my version.