# PTIJ: Does one receive מלקות for posting PTIJ without the correct tag?

Tags: discussion, meta-purim-torah-in-jest

According to משניות מטא ([Purim Torah policy - Allowed, but regulated](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated))

> ...Three are Purim Torah, a tag, a title and a disclaimer.  Rebbi Yitzchok says that all are required...

What happens if one only includes one or two of the three?  Is the punishment מלקות or something else?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

I believe we can learn tag-tag Gezeiras Shava from the tags of a Sefer Torah. And just like there is no Malkus for missing out the tag on a letter of a Sefer Torah, because writing a Sefer Torah is a Mitzvas Aseh, and there is no Malkus for being Mevatel a Mitsvas Aseh, likewise, there is no Malkus for missing out a tag in this forum.